# datatype of variable used for holding input of getchar(),as char instead of int

Tags: c, getchar, kernighan-and-ritchie

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{


    int c;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
       putchar(c);
    putchar(c);     //2nd putchar     
    getch();


}
```

In the above code from the book 'C by Ritchie n Kernighan', the reason for declaring `c` an `int` variable is given as :

> so that `c` may be able to hold the code of `EOF` which is outside the char codes which a `char` datatype can accommodate.

But when I declare c as a char, and input the `EOF`(CTRL-Z + Enter),that value(which is -1 on my computer)does go into c and I immediately end up exiting the while up, just the way it happens if I declare c as an int.
Why do we need to declare c as an int, when char works just fine?? or am I missing something here?

One more thing, in the second `putchar` statement, it should print the last value of c (ie. -1) after having received `EOF` but it doesn't. Why?

Comment: Answered here http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/197625/storing-the-eof-end-of-file-character-in-a-char-type

Comment: Keep your program out of reach from anybody speaking Dutch.  Which has the ij digraph as a common letter, often with character code 255.  Not much of a problem, there are only 25 million of us.

Comment: To address your question in the last paragraph: Before `putchar` prints a value it casts it to `unsigned char`. So, assuming `EOF` is -1 (what it doesn't have to, but most often is), a cast to an (8-bit) `unsigned char` yields `0xFF`, what, depending on your encoding, might be a valid character or not (e.g. in UTF-8 this byte can't occur in any valid sequence). So maybe you just don't see it, although it is outputted. Pipe the output through `hexdump` or write it into a file.

Comment: that's a revelation! @HansPassant

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Difference between int and char in getchar() and putchar()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-and-putchar)

Answer (score 3):

Whether `char` is signed or unsigned is implementation-defined.

If `char` is unsigned, then no `char` value can be equal to `EOF`, the loop will never exit.

If `char` is signed, then `EOF` could be equal to `c`, this is what happens on your machine. But the problem is, this also means, a valid `char` could be equal to `EOF`, causing the loop exit too early.

Answer (score 0):

```
But when I declare c as a char, and input the EOF(CTRL-Z + Enter),that 
value(which is -1 on my computer)does go into c and I immediately end up 
exiting the while up, just the way it happens if I declare c as an int.
```

Recall, getchar is the equivalent of `getc(stdin)`. When you reach `eof`, that condition is set on `stdin` your test within the loop can no longer be true. So the loop terminates regardless of whether you use an int, a char or and unsigned char.

```
One more thing, in the second putchar statement, it should print the 
last value of c (ie. -1) after having received EOF but it doesn't. Why?
```

For the same reason, `EOF` is reached, the loop terminates without calling putchar.