# Difference between int and char in getchar/fgetc and putchar/fputc?

Tags: c

I am trying to learn C on my own and I'm kind of confused with `getchar` and `putchar`:

## 1

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    printf("Enter characters : ");
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
      putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

## 2

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int c;
    printf("Enter characters : ");
    while((c = getchar()) != EOF){
      putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The C library function `int putchar(int c)` writes a character (an unsigned char) specified by the argument char to stdout.

The C library function `int getchar(void)` gets a character (an unsigned char) from stdin. This is equivalent to getc with stdin as its argument.

Does it mean `putchar()` accepts both `int` and `char` or either of them and for `getchar()` should we use an `int` or `char`?

Comment: [Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18013167/995714)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why must the variable used to hold getchar's return value be declared as int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013167/why-must-the-variable-used-to-hold-getchars-return-value-be-declared-as-int)

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc or the opposite way. The age of a question doesn't matter

Answer (score 53, accepted):

TL;DR:

- `char c; c = getchar();` is **wrong, broken and buggy**.
- `int c; c = getchar();` is **correct**.

This applies to `getc` and `fgetc` as well, if not even more so, because one would often read until the end of the file.

---

Always store the return value of `getchar` (`fgetc`, `getc`...) (and `putchar`) initially into a variable of type `int`.

The **argument** to `putchar` can be any of `int`, `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char`; its type doesn't matter, and all of them work the same, even though one might result in positive and other in negative integers being passed for characters above and including `\200` (128).

---

The reason why you **must** use `int` to store the **return value** of both `getchar` and `putchar` is that when the end-of-file condition is reached (or an I/O error occurs), both of them return the value of the macro `EOF` which is a negative integer constant, [(usually `-1`)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4705984/918959).

For `getchar`, if the return value is not `EOF`, it is the read *`unsigned char`* zero-extended to an `int`. That is, assuming 8-bit characters, the values returned can be `0`...`255` or the value of the macro `EOF`; again assuming 8-bit char, there is no way to squeeze these 257 distinct values into 256 so that each of them could be identified uniquely.

---

Now, if you stored it into `char` instead, the effect would depend on whether [the character type is signed or unsigned by default](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2054941/918959)! This varies from compiler to compiler, architecture to architecture. If `char` is signed and assuming `EOF` is defined as `-1`, then **both** `EOF` and character `'\377'` on input would compare equal to `EOF`; they'd be sign-extended to `(int)-1`.

On the other hand, if `char` is unsigned (as it is by default on ARM processors, including [Raspberry PI systems](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=120610&p=815566); and seems to be true for [AIX too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977223/fgetc-does-not-identify-eof?noredirect=1)), there is *no* value that could be stored in `c` that would compare equal to `-1`; including `EOF`; instead of breaking out on `EOF`, your code would output a single `\377` character.

**The danger here is that with signed `char`s the code *seems to be working correctly* even though it is still horribly broken - one of the legal input values is interpreted as `EOF`.** Furthermore, C89, C99, C11 does not mandate a value for `EOF`; it only says that `EOF` is a negative integer constant; thus instead of `-1` it could as well be say `-224` on a particular implementation, which would cause spaces behave like `EOF`.

`gcc` has the switch `-funsigned-char` which can be used to make the `char` unsigned on those platforms where it defaults to signed:

```
% cat test.c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char c;
    printf("Enter characters : ");
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
      putchar(c);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Now we run it with signed `char`:

```
% gcc test.c && ./a.out
Enter characters : sfdasadfdsaf
sfdasadfdsaf
^D
%
```

Seems to be working right. But with unsigned `char`:

```
% gcc test.c -funsigned-char && ./a.out                   
Enter characters : Hello world
Hello world
���������������������������^C
%
```

That is, I tried to press `Ctrl-D` there many times but a `�` was printed for each `EOF` instead of breaking the loop.

Now, again, for the signed `char` case, it cannot distinguish between `char` 255 and `EOF` on Linux, breaking it for binary data and such:

```
% gcc test.c && echo -e 'Hello world\0377And some more' | ./a.out 
Enter characters : Hello world
%
```

Only the first part up to the `\0377` escape was written to stdout.

---

Beware that comparisons between character constants and an `int` containing the unsigned character value might not work as expected (e.g. the character constant `'ä'` in ISO 8859-1 would mean the signed value `-28`. So assuming that you write code that would read input until `'ä'` in ISO 8859-1 codepage, you'd do

```
int c;
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF){
    if (c == (unsigned char)'ä') {
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

---

Due to integer promotion, all `char` values fit into an `int`, and are automatically promoted on function calls, thus you can give any of `int`, `char`, `signed char` or `unsigned char` to `putchar` as an **argument** (not to store its return value), and it would work as expected.

The actual value passed in the integer might be positive or even negative; for example the character constant `\377` would be *negative* on a 8-bit-char system where `char` is signed; however `putchar` (or `fputc` actually) will convert the value to an unsigned char. [C11 7.21.7.3p2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.7.3):

> 2 The fputc function writes the character specified by `c` **(converted to an unsigned char)** to the output stream pointed to by stream [...]

**(emphasis mine)**

I.e. the `fputc` will be guaranteed to convert the given `c` as if by `(unsigned char)c`

Comment: I don't understand, yet, why is the code horrible broken with signed char. After all, doesn't it stores bits? Just like int? I hope to understand what is this danger. After all, if you store the binary value 10 in a char or int variable, it is exactly the same binary number. Therefore, same integer number.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz: You read the value of `getchar()` into an `int`, using, for example, `int c = getchar();`.  Now, if you read an ordinary character, then the value in `c` is non-negative and between 0 and UCHAR_MAX.  If you got EOF, then the value in `c` is negative (usually `-1` though the standard does not mandate that value — EOF must be negative, that's all).  So you can tell the difference easily — when you read the value correctly.  _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ If you store the value from `getchar()` directly into a signed `char` (whether that's explicitly `signed char` or plain `char` on a machine where it is a signed type), then you have one valid character value that can be confused with EOF. Often, that character code is 0xFF, which maps to -1 when the machine uses two's complement arithmetic and 8-bit `char` and EOF is `-1`. The converse problem occurs if plain `char` is an unsigned type; then storing `EOF` directly is never equal to EOF — given `unsigned char c;`, testing `if ((c = getchar()) == EOF)` is never true.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I understand everything you wrote. What I don't get is the danger, since signed char doesn't have a problem at all with EOF being negative and -1. I just feel like saying this: int will have the exact same problem in case it is **unsigned int** . So what's the difference?

Comment: Especially if you live in Turkey, where the letter ÿ (y-umlaut, U+00FF, LATIN SMALL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS) is used, then typing that letter into code that saves the result of `getchar()` into a signed `char` type would be detected as EOF, just as if you'd typed Control-D (Unix) or Control-Z (Windows) — those indicate 'no more data' or EOF.  So, the problem is that a legitimate character (ÿ) is treated as EOF when it should not be.  It's almost as bad as never treating anything as EOF.

Comment: The standard specifies (for [`fgetc()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fgetc.html) but `getchar()` is implemented in terms of `getc(stdin)` and `getc()` is equivalent to `fgetc()`) that: _If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by `stream` is not set and a
next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned
char` converted to an `int` … If the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set, or if the stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and the `fgetc` function returns EOF._

Comment: The concern about `'ä'` is new to me.  It appears that C11 §6.4.4.4 10 is the relevant citation: "If an integer character constant contains a single character or escape sequence, its value is the one that results when an object with type `char` whose value is that of the single character or escape sequence is converted to type `int`."

Comment: I had an argument with someone, about whether or not you need to use `int` vs `char` with `getchar()`, in some comments a while back. Next time I will just point them here!

Answer (score 2):

Always use `int` to save character from `getchar()` as `EOF` constant is of `int` type. If you use `char` then the comparison against `EOF` is not correct.

You can safely pass `char` to `putchar()` though as it will be promoted to `int` automatically.

**Note**:
Technically using `char` will work in most cases, but then you can't have 0xFF character as they will be interpreted as `EOF` due to type conversion. To cover all cases **always** use `int`. As @Ilja put it -- `int` is needed to represent all 256 possible character values **and** the `EOF`, which is 257 possible values in total, which cannot be stored in `char` type.

Comment: " If you use char then the comparison against EOF is not correct." Not sure if I get it. A char variable stores an integer number, so it's just the same, in this case, as using int.

Comment: `EOF` is (int)-1, which is out of range for `char` type.

Comment: Signed char type range is -128, 127.

Comment: on a 32-bit machine `(int)-1` is `0xFFFFFFFF` which is out of range for a `char`, but `(signed char)-1` which is `0xFF` will still get type promoted to `int` during comparison. That's reason why it _usually_ works, but you can't have `0xFF` as valid characters in the stream if you're not using `int` to store the character. I.e., using `int` to store it will be saved as `0x000000FF` which is distinct from `EOF`.

Comment: "Technically using char will work in most cases" is wrong, standard does not mandate that `char` is signed.

Comment: It will work in _most_ cases. I'm not telling it's safe to do so.

Comment: It should say "use int if you expect 0xFF in streams or if you do not know whether `char` is signed or unsigned", that is to say, "always".

Comment: (not that the `EOF` couldn't be defined something else than `-1`).

Comment: True on both accounts, but I prefer to keep the answer terse.

Comment: So you're telling me it's better to read a char value and store it in a int variable? All you have to do is use signed char if it's required so. @AnttiHaapala, you still failed to prove your point in your own answer, and I asked for it many times, in order to understand my mistake. What I concluded is: you prefer to defend your habit of programming with fallacies.

Comment: @JudismarJunior "So you're telling me it's better to read a char value and store it in a int variable?" Yes! Well, at least until you compare it against `EOF`. After that, you're good to store it as `char`.
But I'm also saying `getchar()` returns `int`, and for a reason.

Comment: @JohnLM, I agree it returns *int*. I was trying to understand what was the problem you guys were talking about, but I decided to leave this behind. I am unable to understand, I suppose. I know that comparing a *char* with *int* never had any problem, due to implicit casting (just like comparing int to float).

Comment: @JudismarJunior: I suggest you try to grasp this concept. Otherwise your C programs will be buggy, buggy, buggy.

Comment: @JohnLM `(int)-1` is in range for signed char. C uses value semantics.  The probem is that it is not distinguishable from `(char)-1` when both have been assigned to a variable of the same type.

Comment: @JudismarJunior the accepted answer has a great way of putting this: assuming 8-bit chars you are trying to represent 257 symbols with a type able to represent only 256 symbols. You need 256 chars + EOF. Int can represent those.

Comment: @Ilja, I don't understand: 256 chars + EOF? Did you mean 256 symbols? I still can't understand, given EOF is (int)-1. but I appreciate your comment. I'll try to read the whole answer again. Thanks!

Comment: @Ilja, I've got it now. Thanks again.