# Read file block by block in C

Tags: c, file, file-io, io, buffer

I want to copy the contents of file1 to file2 exactly as they are (keeping spaces and newlines). I specifically want to copy these contents one small block of chars at a time(this is a small segment of a larger project so bear with me).

I have attempted the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAX 5

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    char buffer[MAX];
    int length;
    char c;

    if((fin=fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    if((fout=fopen(argv[2], "w")) == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(1){
        length = 0;
        while((c = fgetc(fin)) != EOF && length < MAX){
            buffer[length++] = (char) c;
        }
        if(length == 0){
            break;
        }
        fprintf(fout, "%s", buffer);
    }
    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fin);
}
```

However, this causes incorrect output to my file2. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: `getc` (and `getchar`, `fgetc`) returns an [**`int`** not **`char`**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-and-putchar). **`int c`**

Comment: is this not "fixed" by typecasting with `(char) c`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-and-putchar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your buffer is not zero-terminated. Use fwrite instead of fprintf:

```
  fwrite(buffer, 1, length, fout);
```

And you should check the error too. So compare return code of `fwrite` to `length` and if it differs, either retry the write of remaining bytes (if positive) or print appropriate error message via `perror("fwrite")` (if return code is negative).

Additionally you may consider opening the files in binary mode which would cause difference on windows, i.e. pass `"rb"` and `"wb"` to `fopen`.

Last but not least, instead of looping and getting one character at a time, consider using `fread` instead:

```
length = fread(buffer, 1, MAX, fin);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example.(with no error checking)

You should use fwrite() since the string you would write to file is not a "null-terminated". And also note that "b" mode is specified with fopen(), which means you want to open the file as a binary file.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define MAX 5
#define FILE_BLOCK_SIZE 50
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    FILE *fin, *fout;
    unsigned char *BufContent = NULL;
    BufContent = (unsigned char*) malloc(FILE_BLOCK_SIZE);
    size_t BufContentSz;

    if((fin=fopen("E:\\aa.txt", "rb")) == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    if((fout=fopen("E:\\bb.txt", "wb")) == NULL){
        perror("fopen");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((BufContentSz = fread(BufContent, sizeof(unsigned char), FILE_BLOCK_SIZE, fin)) > 0) 
    {
        fwrite(BufContent, sizeof(unsigned char), BufContentSz, fout);
    }

    fclose(fout);
    fclose(fin);

    delete BufContent;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, change `char buffer[MAX];` to `int buffer[MAX];`, and `char c;` to `int c;`, for a `char` can be either `signed char` or `unsigned char`, depending on your implementation. In the later case, `c = EOF` will give `c` a large positive number(It's unsigned ,anyway), so the loop will never end. A `int` will be large enough to hold all characters and EOF though.

Then, change your

```
fprintf(fout, "%s", buffer);
```

to

```
fwrite(buffer, 1, length, four);
```

This is because `fprintf(fout, "%s", buffer);` call for a C-style string, with ends with a `'\0'`, but your `buffer` isn't zero-terminated. As a result, the program will keep copying the stuff in the stack, until a `'\0'` is met, leaving lots of garbage in file2.