# Behavior of fgetc() function in C

Tags: c, linux, assembly, fgetc

I am looking for an easy way to manage file opening and closing in x86-64 assembly on linux. I thought the easiest way would be to write a c file containing functions that I could call without having to worry about stability. So I wrote this function :

```
struct PORT open_port(char *filename, int mode) {
   struct PORT port;
   port.p = 0;
   if (mode) {
   if (filename == "stdout")
     port.f = stdout;
   else
     port.f = fopen(filename, "wb+");
   } else {
   if (filename == "stdin")
      port.f = stdin;
  else 
     port.f = fopen(filename, "rb");
  }
  return port;
}
```

And then I read the port like so:

```
char readchar(struct PORT *port)
{
  char r;
  if ((*port).p)
    r = (*port).p;
  else 
    r = fgetc((*port).f);
  (*port).p = 0;
  return r;
}
```

Where `PORT.p` is a char which contains the character at the current position and `PORT.f` a file pointer. Then I call those function in my assembler code by putting the parameters in `%rdi` and `%rsi`.

Everything works as expected when I am reading an ordinary file, but the `stdin` support doesn't work. I know `stdin` is supposed to be the value `0` and when I debug my code, I can see that the value holding the file pointer is indeed `0`, but when the code gets to the `fgetc()` call, it seg faults. If I write plainly `fgetc(0);` in my function, there is also a segmentation fault. I don't get how the `fgetc()` function can tell the difference between the `stdin` and a normal `0`.

How can I read `stdin` using this (or a very similar pattern)? Or if it's all wrong, what should I do to open files in x64 assembly? There is certainly something I am not getting regarding how it works, help would be greatly appreciated.

(For those who are wondering what's the point of this all: it's to be able to read the next character without [in appearance] moving the file pointer, so there is a peekchar function that sets `PORT.p` if it's unset, so `p` can hold the value until it's read)

Comment: `stdin` is a `FILE*`, not an integer file descriptor. So it is not 0.

Comment: The file descriptor for `stdin` may be 0, but the `FILE *` for `stdin` is definitely not 0. Also, the proper way to write `(*port).p` is `port->p`.

Comment: Detail: `char r;` --> `int r;`

Comment: "wondering what's the point of this all:" --> To peek,  just use `c=fgetc(f); ungetc(c,f);`

Comment: [the `int r;` is not only a detail](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Comment: Use `strcmp(filename, "stdout")==0` instead of `filename == "stdout"`.

Comment: The common idiom to access fields of pointees is `port->f` and not `(*port).f`.

Comment: That's it! @Marian you got it! I was only comparing the pointers, but I can't do that since I'm calling it from another file. And thank you everyone for all your helpful comments!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was working when compiled with C, but not with the assembler code because of the wrong use of the `==` operator.

Since the C compiler only defined the string `"stdin"` once, the string pointers where equal which made it look like it worked, but when calling it from the assembler code the pointer changed and the condition couldn't be met.

Replacing `==` with `strcmp()` solved it