# does the array created by malloc() add a '\0' character to the end of the array?

Tags: c, arrays

i have a code that prints  the content of a txt file reversely as a string.İ store the every characters of my string in the txt file by using `malloc()` function.İt works properly but it prints the content of the with a preceding `'\0'` What is the reason?

```
void veriyitersyazdir(FILE *file)
{
    char metin;          // that gets the every single char of my string
    int boyutsayac=0;    // that stores my string's size
    char *metinarr=NULL; // that is my malloc() array pointer
    int dongusayac;      // that is a counter variable that is used to print my string reversely.

    system("cls");

    file = fopen("C:\\metin.txt", "r");

    do {
        metin = fgetc(file);
        if (metin==EOF) {
            break;
        }

        boyutsayac++;
    } while (1);

    metinarr = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char)*boyutsayac);
    fseek( file, 0, SEEK_SET);
    for (dongusayac = 0; dongusayac < boyutsayac; dongusayac++) {
        metin = fgetc(file);
        metinarr[dongusayac]= metin;
    }

    fseek( file, 0 , SEEK_SET);
    for (; dongusayac >=0; dongusayac--) {
        printf("%c", metinarr[dongusayac]);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

content of the txt file:Mustafa Mutlu

the output of the codes: UltuM afatsuM

Comment: `for (; dongusayac >=0; dongusayac--)` : `dongusayac` begins with one greater value.

Comment: `metin = fgetc(file);` where `metin` is a **char** is utterly wrong. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc/35356684#35356684. `fgetc` returns an **int**, you should honour that contract, because a **char** possibly cannot represent EOF (on systems where char is unsigned). It will still be wrong on systems with signed char too, just a bit differently.

Comment: This would be why you should always write source code in English. Because you might need help with it eventually.

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem, as noted by bluepixy, comes from the `for` loop that you use to read which increments `dongusayac` one more than the number of characters read.

That is always the case in a `for` loop as it increases the variable and then checks if it still fits the condition.  So the last increase never fits the condition.

Here is a cleaner way to do what you're doing:

```
void reverse() {
    FILE *file;
    size_t size;
    int i;

    if (!(file = fopen("c:\\metin.txt", "r"))) {
            printf("error opening file\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    fseek(file, 0L, SEEK_END);
    size = ftell(file);

    char *content = malloc(size);           // allocate memory for the full text file
    fseek(file, 0, SEEK_SET);               // rewind the file cursor
    fread(content, 1, size, file);

    for (i = size - 1; i >= 0; i --) {      // output contents in reverse order
            printf("%c", content[i]);
    }

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: I agree, but it certainly isn't a '\0'.

Comment: The variable names were so confusing I didn't notice.  I'll update my answer to reflect that.