# cant write to file after using fgetc/getc (Windows)

Tags: c, windows, file

I'm developing on Windows (VS 2010) a simple program using fgetc and I recognized that after I'm using this function (same behavior with getc) I can't write to the file although I opened it with appropriate permissions.

Here is a simple program I wrote to check what the hell is going on:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    FILE *f = NULL;
    char ch = 0;
    int bytes = 0;

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    ch = fgetc(f);
    bytes = fwrite("1234", sizeof(char), 4, f);
    printf("%d", bytes);
    fflush(f);
    fclose(f);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

The program prints 4 and exit without any error, but the file content remain the same.
After I research it a little bit I found out that if I add this line (that doing "nothing"):

```
fseek(f, 0, SEEK_CUR);
```

The program working as I expected, and the file content changed.

all the code after adding this line:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) 
{
    FILE *f = NULL;
    char ch = 0;
    int bytes = 0;

    f = fopen(argv[1], "r+");
    ch = fgetc(f);
    fseek(f, 0, SEEK_CUR)
    bytes = fwrite("1234", sizeof(char), 4, f);
    printf("%d", bytes);
    fflush(f);
    fclose(f);

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Does anyone know why is this happen and how to solve it?

Thanks a lot,
Hanan.

Comment: First of all [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) doesn't return a `char`. This is actually very important.

Comment: As for your problem, what is the original content of the file? Just a single byte?

Comment: [some stuff that might happen if you use `fgetc` and friends with `char`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35356684/918959)

Comment: And `sizeof(char)` is 1, since return value of `sizeof` is number of `char`s ("bytes")

Comment: BTW, is your intention really to open the file in text mode?

Comment: I wrote the example only to demonstrate my problem I didn't really care about those problems since the program does works. Thanks for the good practice tips.

Comment: The content of the file was just 30 times 'a' character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yeby3zcb.aspx

> When the "r+", "w+", or "a+" access type is specified, both reading and writing are enabled (the file is said to be open for "update"). However, when you switch from reading to writing, the input operation must encounter an EOF marker. If there is no EOF, you must use an intervening call to a file positioning function. The file positioning functions are fsetpos, fseek, and rewind. When you switch from writing to reading, you must use an intervening call to either fflush or to a file positioning function

So because you probably haven't hit EOF then you need to position the seek position so your call to fseek is exactly what you needed.

The comments on the return code from `fgetc` are important too but aren't affecting your code at the moment.

Answer (score 2):

It does not work because the C standard (C11 draft n1570 7.21.5.3 in *The
fopen
function paragraph 7*; and all previous versions as well) says it does not have to work.

> When  a  file  is  opened  with  update  mode  (
>   `+`
>   as  the  second  or  third  character  in  the
>   above 
>   list  of
>   mode
>   argument  values),  both  input  and  output  may  be  performed  on  the
>   associated  stream.   However,  output  shall  not  be  directly  followed  by  input  without  an
>   intervening  call  to  the
>   `fflush`
>   function  or  to  a  file  positioning  function  (
>   `fseek`
>   ,
>   `fsetpos`
>   ,or
>   `rewind`
>   ),  and  **input  shall  not  be  directly  followed  by  output  without  an
>   intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input operation encounters *end-of-file*.**  [--]

---

Notice that if the file was initially *empty*, then `fgetc` would have returned `EOF` and `"1234"` would have been written.

Comment: So what do I need to do if I want to write something in the file based on what I read. for example, if I want to replace every byte after 'a' char in the file with 'b' (if the content of the file was "asdfasdf" I want it to be "abdfabdf")

Comment: ah now that is trickier. You cannot seek backwards; instead standardwise, you'd have to use `ftell` to tell the file position *before* `fgetc`; then after `fgetc` seek to it using `fseek` with `SEEK_SET`.

All in all, if you need to do these modifications a lot, it'd be more worthwhile to use an operating-system specific mechanism for memory-mapping the file.