# Counter depending on getchar return value gives wrong oputput

Tags: c, eof, getchar

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    char ch;
    int count;

    while((ch=getchar())!=EOF){
        if(ch==' '){
           count++;
        }
    }
    printf("total words is %d",count);
    return 0;
}
```

my C code is here ,I am confused where I put ctrl+Z directly in windows ,it turn out count is 2?why it go loop for two and where comes the space?

Comment: Assigning what is returned from `getchar()` to variable having type `char` is bad because it will truncate the data and it make distinguishing of a charcter and `EOF` impossible in typical environment. Using `int` is good.

Comment: Related, if not a dupe to: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35356322/694576

Comment: Please read manuals for all library functions that you want to use.

Comment: The question's title is not very helpful.

Comment: @alk Cannot make it much meaningful, anyway, tried... :)

Answer (score 4):

The biggest issue here is, you've left `count` uninitialized. So, whether the `if` is success or not, you'll end up reading a unitialized local variable which invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You should always initialize the local variables, like

```
 int count = 0;
```

That said, `getchar()` returns an `int`. Storing that into a `char` is wrong because in case the function returns `EOF` (as you expect here), it'll not fit into a `char`.

Regarding `EOF` marco, quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.1

> `EOF`
>   which expands to an **integer constant expression**, with type `int` and a negative value, that
>   is returned by several functions to indicate *end-of-file*, that is, no more input from a
>   stream;

So, you should change the type of `ch` from `char` to `int`, like

```
int ch = 0;
```

Comment: instead of saying thank u, you can accept an answer if it solves your problem.