# Usage of getchar() and fflush(stdin)

Tags: c

I am supposed to come up with a program to calculate the number of words, vowels, lowercase letters and alphabetic letters for an assignment.

And I have two questions, why cant I use `while (getchar() != '\n')` instead of assigning it to a variable `ch` and why `fflush(stdin)` must be used???

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <ctype.h>

    int main(void)
    {

        char ch, repeat;
        int numVowel = 0, numLower = 0, numAlpha = 0, numWords = 0, inWord = 0;

        // Tells user what the program does
        printf("This program prompts a user to enter a piece of text and\ncalculates the number of alphabetic letters, lowercase letters, \nvowels and words in that piece of text.\n\n");


        do
        {
             printf("Type the text here (hit \"Enter\" to end): ");  

             while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n')         //*dont understand this part*
            {
                    if (ch == ' ')                             
                        inWord = 0;

            else if (inWord == 0 && isalpha(ch))     
            {                                       
                inWord = 1;
                numWords += 1;
            }

            if (isalpha(ch))             
                numAlpha += 1;

            if (islower(ch))             
                numLower += 1;

            switch(ch)                   
            {
                case 'a':
                case 'A':
                case 'e':
                case 'E':
                case 'i':
                case 'I':
                case 'o':
                case 'O':
                case 'u':
                case 'U': numVowel += 1;
                          break;
            }
        }

        printf("\nNumber of alphabetical letters: %-4d\n", numAlpha);
        printf("Number of lowercase letters   : %-4d\n", numLower);
        printf("Number of vowels              : %-4d\n", numVowel);
        printf("Number of words               : %-4d\n\n", numWords);

        do
        {
            printf("Do you want to try again? (Y/N): ");

            scanf("%c", &repeat);
            repeat = toupper(repeat);
            if (repeat != 'Y' && repeat != 'N')         
                printf("Invalid answer. Please enter 'Y' or 'N'.\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);               //*why is this required?*               

        } while (repeat != 'N' && repeat != 'Y');       

        printf("\n");
        fflush(stdin);                   //*why is this required?*
        numVowel = 0, numLower = 0, numAlpha = 0, numWords = 0, inWord = 0;  

    } while (repeat == 'Y');           


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think 2nd `fflush(stdin)` unnecessary .

Comment: [`getchar` returns an **int**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY it shouldn't be used at all! It's UB.

Answer (score 1):

> why cant I use `while (getchar() != '\n')` instead of assigning it to a variable `ch`

If you do that, you won't be able to use the value returned by `getchar()` in the block of code in the `while` statement: the `if` statements, the `else if` statement, the `switch` statement.

> why `fflush(stdin)` must be used?

`fflush` is meant to be used for output streams, not input streams. Hence, `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fflush<sup>1</sup>.

It seems that the intent of `fflush(stdin)` in your code is to read and discard everything until the end of the line. Write a function to do that.

```
void readAndDiscardRestOfLine(FILE* in)
{
   int c;
   while ( (c = fgetc(in)) != EOF && c != '\n');
}
```

and use

```
readAndDiscardRestOfLine(stdin);
```

instead of

```
fflush(stdin);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>POSIX extends the definition of `fflush` for input streams. However, it extends them only to seekable devices. The extension does not apply to `stdin`.

Comment: hi but if i assign ch = getchar() and use while (ch != '\n'), it does not work as well

Comment: @12johnny, `while ( (ch = getchar()) != '\n' )` does two things. It assigns the character read from `stdin` to `ch` and stops the loop if the value of `ch` is `'\n'`. You need both of them in your code.

Comment: `fflush` on input streams is defined by POSIX 2008.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala, if you can provide a link, I will happy to update my answer.

Comment: the link is in your answer already (though it doesn't say that this is 2008, but not 2001).

Answer (score -1):

The problem occurs when you scan a character using `scanf("%c", &repeat);`  Generally a user will enter the character 'y' or 'n' and then press enter. The character is read into the `repeat` variable, but the enter character (\n) remains in the buffer.

When you try to read the character again, in the loop, you will read this `\n` not a 'y' or 'n' as you expect.

The solution for this is to change the scanf statement to

```
scanf(" %c", &repeat);
```

The space character in fromt of the %c will read any whitespace character and only store the 'y' or 'n' in repeat. In this case, you will not need fflush.

`fflush(stdin)` is not a good practice. For more information you should look at [Using fflush(stdin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin)