# Why doesn't the first letter of my string print?

Tags: c, scanf

I'm trying to write a piece of code that asks for user input to type in their name. It's then supposed to read each character of their name and format it however I choose (in the code below, it adds a new line after each character).

The problem I'm having is when someone types in their name, it doesn't print the first letter but prints out the rest.

For example, if I were to type in Sneek, it only displays neek.

Now I'm a beginner at programming and even more so with C so I was wondering if there is a problem with my scanf statement or the loop.

Also, if i type in Sneek it displays neek but if I type in Sneek again, it displays it as Sneek so I'm assuming theres nothing wrong with the loop?

I've searched for quite a while on this issue but I can't seem to find any answers, any help would be much appreciated.

```
char ch;
printf("Please enter name:  ");
ch = scanf("%c", &ch);

while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    printf("%c\n", ch);

}
return 0;
```

Comment: `getchar` intentionally returns an `int`, not a `char`! `ch = scanf(..., &ch)` is plain wrong. Read the documentation of functions you use!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Difference between int and char in getchar/fgetc and putchar/fputc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Comment: The accepted answer is the same as that in the duplicate. Therefore this question should be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues in the code fragment:

- The `ch = scanf("%c", &ch);` serves no purpose and does not even properly read a byte from the file into `ch`. Note that `scanf` does store the byte into `ch`, but it is immediately overwritten as you store the return value into `ch` as well. Just remove this line.
- `while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) { printf("%c\n", ch); }` is correct for your purpose but the type of `ch` **must** be `int` instead of `char` to accommodate all values of `unsigned char` and the special value `EOF`. As currenly written, your code will fail to stop at end of file on platforms where `char` is an unsigned type.

Comment: I agree that the `scanf()` is not helpful, but what's with the "does not even properly read a byte from the file" issue?  It looks good to me, unless you're complaining that it doesn't check whether a character was read successfully, which should be characterized differently (as "you don't check that the I/O operation worked").

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: the offending `scanf()` reads a byte from the file, stores it into `ch` and then returns 1 if successful, which in turn gets stored into the same variable `ch`. For argument's sake, the byte is properly read from the stream, but its value is not properly stored for further use ;-)

Comment: Ah; I missed the assignment to `ch` (as well as using it in the argument list).  Yes; that's appalling — and "does not properly read" is accurate.  I should have spotted that abuse, but maybe you could point out how bad it is (it may not be obvious to everyone).

Answer (score 2):

Comment out the `ch = scanf("%c", &ch);`. You are consuming the first character there and never print it.

Answer (score 0):

This statement reads a character from standard input via `scanf`.

```
ch = scanf("%c", &ch);
```

This loop reads characters from standard input via `getchar`.

```
while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF) {
    printf("%c\n", ch);

}
```

What happens to the first character after it is read with `scanf`? It is overwritten with the result of `getchar`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem.  You get the first character.  After that, you get and print characters until EOF.

It's not printing the first character because you didn't tell it to.