# getchar() in a for loop condition

Tags: c, for-loop, eof, getchar

Consider following code:

```c
int main()
{
    char c;
    for(;(c=getchar())+1;)
        printf("%c\n",c);
}
```

It gets characters what I enter in terminal and prints them. When I remove `+1` in condition, program works but it doesnt stop when `EOF` (Ctrl+D) signal. When I change it to `+2` same problem.

My question is how that `+1` work? Is it something related to `getchar()` or `for` loop?

Comment: Because `EOF` is typically defined as `-1`, and `-1 + 1 = 0`. In short, don't do that. What you should do is `while((c=getchar()) != EOF)`

Comment: And, `char c;` --> `int c;` because `getchar()` returns `int`.

Comment: To emphasise on what @user3386109 and @WeatherVane wrote: you have to use both measures! EOF **typically** is `-1`, it is not guaranteed! General advice: Read the documentation of functions and macros, etc. you use! It all can be found in any C book. Along with what an addition means in C (the mathematical basics should be tought at school)..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35356684/2681632 a lengthy but good answer of the dangers of `char c = getchar()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the int value of `EOF` is `-1`, so what you're doing is loop until the expression`(c=getchar())+1`) gets the value 0 which is when you read `EOF`  (where value of exrpession is: -1+1=0). Also as wll pointed out in the comments you should declare c as int since `getchar() returns int.`

Answer (score 1):

for statement works with limits known already 
if you want a conditional loop use while :

```
int main()
{
int c;
while ((c=getchar()) != eof())
    printf("%c\n",c);
}
```

Comment: The return type of `getchar()` is `int`, not `char`.  Do not use `char`.

Answer (score 1):

Reason why it works for +1 only.
Prototype : int getchar(void);

Return Value

- On success, the character read is returned (promoted to an int value).
- The return type is int to accommodate for the special value EOF, which indicates failure(-1).
- If the standard input was at the end-of-file, the function returns EOF and sets the eof indicator (feof) of stdin.
- If some other reading error happens, the function also returns EOF, but sets its error indicator (ferror) instead.