# C language, read new line character from external file

Tags: c, arrays, file, fgetc

Hello guys i have an external file like this :

[image: screenshot]

I want to read all character (include space and new line) to my 2-Dimensional(row and column) array, but i failed to do that. Example, in that file at line 10 and column 1 (the bottom left corner) there is a '/' character. I want to put '/' in my array[9][0] (index in array start from 0 not 1), so every character is located in array as same as the file.

Here is my code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
/** my index array variable, i for row and j for column */
int i;
int j;

/** varible to read character */
char c;

/** array for the input. The file will not consist more than 17 rows and 2017 columns*/
char input[17][2017];

/** pointer to a file */
FILE *fp;

/** read that file. (my code and that file are located in the same place) */
fp = fopen("bangun.in", "r");

/** start reading the file */
i = 0;
j = 0;
while ( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF){
        if (c != 0) {
            input[i][j]=c;
        }
        else if (c == '\n') {
            input[i][j]=c;
            printf("get in");
            i++;
        }
    j++;
}
fclose(fp);
return 0;
}
```

if my algoritm is worng, could you tell me how to it? my aim is copy all character with the position into my array.

Comment: [`int c;`!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Comment: i have tried, it didn't work

Comment: Gabriel's answer is correct, mine is a criticism of your code. `getchar` returns an *int*, not `char`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your if logic is wrong, if c == 0 (else condition) it will never be a new line.