# Replacing a line in a text file with a string

Tags: c, file, multidimensional-array, file-handling

I am learning file handling in C. I wrote code to replace a line in a file with a string input by the user. The replacing progress itself works great, but somehow **the first line is always empty** and I am able to understand what goes wrong.

Additionally I have some additional questions about file handling itself and about tracking down the mistakes in my code. I understand by now that I should have used perror() and errno. This will be the next thing I will read on.

- Why shouldn't I use **"w+"** establishing the file stream? (A user on here told me to better not use it, unfortunately I couldn't get an explanation)
- I tried to use gdb to find the mistake, but when I display my fileStored array I get only numbers, since its obviously an int array, how could I improve the displaying of the variable
- What would be a good approach in gdb to track the mistake down I made in the code?

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define MAXLENGTH 100

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    FILE *fileRead;
    char fileName[MAXLENGTH],newLine[MAXLENGTH];
    int fileStored[MAXLENGTH][MAXLENGTH];
    short lineNumber, lines = 0;
    int readChar;

    printf("Input the filename to be opened:");
    int i = 0;
    while((fileName[i] = getchar()) != '\n' && fileName[i] != EOF && i < MAXLENGTH){
        i++;
    }
    fileName[i] = '\0';

    if((fileRead = fopen(fileName, "r")) == NULL){
        printf("Error: File not found!\n");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    i = 0;
    while((readChar = fgetc(fileRead)) != EOF){
        if(readChar == '\n'){
            fileStored[lines][i] = readChar;
            i = 0;
            lines++;
        }
        fileStored[lines][i] = readChar;
        i++;
    }

    fclose(fileRead);
    fileRead = fopen(fileName, "w");

    printf("Input the content of the new line:");

    i = 0;
    while((newLine[i] = getchar()) != '\n' && newLine[i] != EOF && i < MAXLENGTH){
        i++;
    }
    newLine[i] = '\0';

    printf("There are %d lines.\nInput the line number you want to replace:",lines);
    scanf("%d",&lineNumber);

    if((lineNumber > lines) || (lineNumber <=0)){
        printf("Error: Line does not exist!");
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    int j = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < lines; i++){
        if(i == lineNumber-1){
            fprintf(fileRead,"\n%s",newLine);
            continue;
        }
        do{
            fputc(fileStored[i][j],fileRead);
            j++;
        }while(fileStored[i][j] != '\n');
        j = 0;
    }       

    fclose(fileRead);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: 1) `while((fileName[i] = getchar()) != '\n' && fileName[i] != EOF && i < MAXLENGTH){ i++; }` --> `while((readChar = getchar()) != '\n' && readChar != EOF && i < MAXLENGTH-1){ fileName[i++] = readChar; }`

Comment: 2) `fprintf(fileRead,"\n%s",newLine);` --> `fprintf(fileRead, "%s\n", newLine);`

Comment: 3) `int fileStored[MAXLENGTH][MAXLENGTH];` --> `char  fileStored[MAXLENGTH][MAXLENGTH];`

Comment: 4) `do{
            fputc(fileStored[i][j],fileRead);
            j++;
        }while(fileStored[i][j] != '\n');` --> `fputs(fileStored[i], fileRead);`

Comment: 5) `while((readChar = fgetc(fileRead)) != EOF){
        if(readChar == '\n'){
            fileStored[lines][i] = readChar;
            i = 0;
            lines++;
        }
        fileStored[lines][i] = readChar;
        i++;
    }` --> `while((readChar = fgetc(fileRead)) != EOF){
  fileStored[lines][i++] = readChar;
  if(readChar == '\n'){
   fileStored[lines++][i] = 0;
   i = 0;
  }
 }`. Use `fgets` instead of.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but I need some more explanation to your code.

I think it should stay `int fileStored` since fgetc should return an int and i am passing the value to it from readChar. I also don't like putting `i++` into brackets, since it is not a clear way to represent the code.

In general the code works neatly except the first line missing, what I don't understand yet.

Comment: 3) It does not have to be `int`.

Comment: 1) `fileName[i] != EOF` You should not compare equal `char` type with EOF.

Comment: 2) `"\n%s"` : It is probably a mistake to output a newline before the contents. It should be line-by-line processing.

Comment: 4) Because it is incrementing after outputting the character, the comparison of the termination condition is incorrect.

Comment: 5) Paul Ogilvie already pointed out. It is not correct for reasons similar to (4). Also There is no restriction on the reading line size. It is better to use `fgets`.

Comment: [getchar(), fgetc() et al always return `int`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc). `EOF` is an `int` value, not `char`. You're correct that `fgetc`  returns an int, yet half of your code is storing the value into `char`s and only then comparing against `EOF`.

Comment: 5-1) Also, it is better to use fgets for cases where there is no newline  in the last line.

Comment: Likely duplicate of [How to replace the text into a particular location of a file by passing the argument via command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51317431/how-to-replace-the-text-into-a-particular-location-of-a-file-by-passing-the-argu/51319999#51319999)