# How to replace the text into a particular location of a file by passing the argument via command line argument

Tags: c

My  intention is to read the second element in the 1st row and replace it with the value which we pass as an command line argument and replace it in the input.txt file

Input file:logic.txt

one=1234

two=3456

I want my file to be changed like this after compiling the code.

./a.out 1567

Currently i am getting output like this

./filelogic 1567

1567=1234

two=5678

Expected Output file should be modified like this after the compilation

logic.txt

one=1567

two=5678

```
        char buf[MAXSIZE] = {};
        int num = 0;
        int i = 0;

        num = atoi(argv[1]);

        printf("%d",num);

       FILE *fp1;
              fp1 = fopen("logic.txt","r");//currently reading the file.
       if(fp1 != NULL)
       {

                 fseek(fp1,3,0);//Need to Move the pointer to the 3rd position where i need to replace the num(fseek(fp1,??,0))-->how we can achieve that.

                 //Using which method i can replace the num value into a file (means need to replace 1234 inplace of 1567)

               //Once the changes are done need to replace in the same file.

                fread(buf, 1, MAXSIZE, fp1);

                printf("%s\n",buf);

                 fclose(fp1);


       }else {
                printf("Cannot open file"");
                    exit(1);
       }
```

Could someone guide me to resolve this issue?Thanks in advance

Comment: Replacement in files (aka overwriting) requires that old and new contents have exact same length. Otherwise, you have either to read old file and write a new whereby replacing what you want Or you read file into memory buffer, replace things (which may move parts of buffer contents) and rewrite file from memory buffer. Of course, for the latter the buffer has to have sufficient size to hold file contents before and after replacement.

Answer (score 2):

You **can** make replacements to a file *in-place*, but you **should not** do this in practice. You will likely **corrupt the file** if you attempt to replace characters and do not make an exact one-to-one replacement of characters already in the file.

To safely change the contents of a file, read the entire file contents into memory, make the changes needed, and then truncate the current file and write the new contents to the truncated file. (if the file is too large for in-memory operations, then use a temporary file)

You do not want to use `atoi` to convert the string `"1567"` to an integer. You are replacing *characters* in a file, not integer values in a binary file, so work with characters instead.

Your project is complicated by only wanting to replace the text after the first `'='` sign. This may or may not be on the first line of the file, so you will need some flag to indicate when the first `'='` is found and the replacement is made. (once the replacement is made, you can simply break your read loop and close the file -- but below the example output all lines for convenience)

Any time you close a file after *writing* to it, you should validate the **return** of `fclose` to catch any stream errors, or errors that occurred on the last write that will not be apparent until the next file operation.

With those cautions and caveats in mind, you could do something similar to:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAXSIZE 64          /* max line/buffer size */
#define FNAME "logic.txt"   /* default file name */
#define REPLACE "1567"      /* default replacement text */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    char buf[MAXSIZE] = "";         /* line buffer */
    const char *str = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : REPLACE; /* replacement string */
    int replaced = 0;               /* flag indicating replacement made */
    FILE *fp = fopen (FNAME, "r+"); /* open file reading/writing */

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading/writing */
        perror ("fopen-FNAME");
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets (buf, MAXSIZE, fp)) {  /* read each line in file */
        if (!replaced) {                /* if replacement not yet made */
            char *p = strchr (buf, '=');    /* search for '=' in line */
            if (p) {                        /* if found */
                size_t plen = 0;            /* var for length to end */
                p++;                        /* advance past '=' sign */
                plen = strlen (p);          /* get length to end  */

                if (plen < strlen (str)) {  /* check avail length */
                    fprintf (stderr, "error: not enough space in line.\n");
                    return 1;
                }
                strcpy (p, str);                    /* copy str to p */
                if (fseek (fp, -plen, SEEK_CUR)) {  /* backup plen chars */
                    perror ("fseek(fp)");
                    return 1;
                }
                fputs (p, fp);  /* overwite contents with replacement */
                replaced = 1;   /* set flag indicating replacement   */
            }                   /* (you can break, and remove output */
        }                       /*  here if not writing to stdout)   */
        fputs (buf, stdout);    /* output lines to stdout (optional) */
    }
    if (fclose (fp) == EOF)     /* always validate close-after-write */
        perror ("fclose-FNAME");

    return 0;
}
```

Using your file `logic.txt` as an example input, and naming the executable `filelogic` as you have, the use and operation of the code above yields:

**logic.txt File Before**

```
$ cat logic.txt
one=1234

two=3456
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./filelogic
one=1567

two=3456
```

**logic.txt File After**

```
$ cat logic.txt
one=1567

two=3456
```

Again, this is fine for a learning endeavor, but in practice, avoid making changes to files *in-place* as the risk of inadvertent file corruption far outweighs writing a new file with the changes.

Comment: Thanks alot Rankin...Logic really nice

Comment: Glad to help. These are good learning exercises because they force you to put your accounting hat on and account for whether there is enough space in the line to make the replacement (you should approach all memory usage and I/O with the same attention to each byte). Good luck with your coding.

Comment: Need your suggestion on the implement the functionality given below