# What is delay() in C? Is it a system function?

Tags: c++, c, function, methods, delay

In a book, I saw a piece of code.

[image: command line aurguments]

but when I ran this code it said:
C:\Users\dipankar\Desktop\cla.cpp   [Error] 'delay' was not declared in this scope

They used it without proper documentation. They only said that "delay() is used to delay the execution of the next line by few milliseconds"!!.
please help.

Comment: You should always post the code and not a screenshot of the code.

Comment: unable code with C  here..can you help me, buddy?

Comment: There is a pretty straightforward help in the editor about this: indent by four spaces, and the line will be highlighted automatically.

Comment: Get a better (and more modern) book.

Comment: Note: under unix you could use select() to sleep n seconds

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The book you are reading is crap. Avoid the book and tell others to do the same.

- `<conio.h>` is a system-specific header and not guaranteed to be available on many platforms.
- [The result of `fgetc` must never be stored in a `char` variable.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322)
- [The function `feof` must never be used in a loop condition.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941)

The book probably comes from the 1980s or early 1990s. There is a function `delay` in Turbo Pascal that takes milliseconds. Maybe that's the one the author means.

Answer (score 3):

It's a millisecond delay function.  Where it's defined depends a lot on what platform/toolchain you're compiling against.  Often it would be found in `<time.h>`

Comment: i have added #include<time.h> but same result !!

Comment: Again, it greatly depends on your platform and toolchain.  We have no idea what you're targeting or what would be "standardly" available.  We can't even really suggest a modern equivalent without that info.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any sleep function as part of the C standard. However, you would use `nanosleep` (https://linux.die.net/man/2/nanosleep) for this purpose in Linux.