# EOF reached before...EOF

Tags: c, eof, dev-c++

I am doing  a very simple homework that requires me to output a file's content, but I unexpectedly reach EOF before doing anything.
The file contains just the word "pig" and for some reason EOF returns 16. I am using Dev-Cpp and the program is in C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("C:/Users/myusername/Desktop/numeri.txt", "r");
    char c;
    if (fp!=NULL)
    {
        printf ("File opened correctly.\n");
        c=fgetc(fp);
        printf("%d\n", feof(fp)); //FEOF EQUALS 16 FOR SOME REASON
        while (feof(fp)==0)
        {
            putchar(c);
            c=fgetc(fp);
        }
        fclose(fp);
        system("PAUSE");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("File cannot be opened.\n");
        system("PAUSE");
        exit(1);
    }
    system("PAUSE");
}
```

Comment: Firstly `char c` should be `int c`, note that `fgetc` returns `int` and `putchar` takes `int`. Secondly please read [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong])

Comment: Also do not use `system("pause");` (see [system(“pause”); - Why is it wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong) )

Comment: `int c; while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { putchar(c); }`

Comment: Still not working.

Comment: [Difference between int and char in getchar/fgetc and putchar/fputc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/35356322/995714)

Comment: You problem statement "EOF returns 16" is unclear. If you are still using `feof`, remove all traces of it from the code. It does have a use, but not here.

Comment: I've tested "c" 's value, it's -1. How do I fix? Btw, thanks for the replies, expecially for the one explaining why system("pause") is bad, I'll keep it in mind.

Comment: That is the value of `EOF`, -1. It does need "fixing", just understanding. This is why `c` must be type `int`.

Comment: I've removed feof. Now the problem is that "c" equals -1. Before you ask, I've checked the directory that I specified in the program many times so that isn't the problem.

Comment: Please read my previous comment, and re-read all of them.

Comment: So, now c is an int. EOF is given if we reach end of the file, right? But my file isn't an empty file, it contains the word "pig". Now either everything I've been taught about files is false or I'm not seeing something.

Comment: If `EOF` is the return value from the *first* `fgetc` call, then the file is not the one you think it is, it is empty. Have you flushed the output buffer? `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: alright..but now it's only printing "ig".

Comment: I am reading your code by remote vision. You still have `c=fgetc(fp);` before the revised loop `while((c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) { putchar(c); }` so the "p" is not getting printed. Think carefully about what you are doing.

Comment: when responding to an error indication (that is returned from a system function) 1) the error message should be output to `stderr`, not `stdout` 2) should also output the reason the system thinks the error occurred.  So this statement: `printf("File cannot be opened.\n");` should be: `perror ("File cannot be opened.\n");`

Answer (score 0):

per the man page for `feof()`:

The function feof() tests the  end-of-file  indicator
    for the stream pointed to by stream, 
    *returning nonzero if it is set*.

So the only expectation is the returned value is 0 or non-zero.

So there is nothing wrong with the value `16`

here is a proposed version of the code:

1. it cleanly compiles
2. it performs the desired function
3. it implements the comments to the question
4. readability and understanding is enhanced by separating code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a single blank line.

and now the code

```
#include <stdio.h>   // fopen(), printf(), perror(). fclose(), fgetc()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen("big.txt", "r");

    if (fp!=NULL)
    {
        printf ("File opened correctly.\n");

        int c=fgetc(fp);

        while (EOF != c)
        {
            putchar(c);
            c=fgetc(fp);
        }

        fclose(fp);
        return 0;
    }

    else
    {
        perror ("File cannot be opened.\n");
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }
}
```

Note: the file: `big.txt` just contains `big`

here is the resulting output:

```
File opened correctly.
big
```