# Uninitialized char variable

Tags: c

When compiling my code below, it says that `f` is uninitialized. How do I initialize a character and why do I need to? My intention is to end the loop when `f` is entered and stored in `c`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
  int count= 0;
  char c,f;

  printf("Input a character:\n");
  do
  {
    c = getchar();
    count++
  }while(c!=f);
  printf("number of characters: %d", count);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you don't initialize it, what are you expecting `c!=f` to compare with?

Comment: `f = 'E'` will resolve the issue, you have to set value of variable `f`

Comment: Your question has never been [accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) before.

Comment: [The return value of `getchar` must be stored into an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35356322/918959).

Comment: This has nothing to do with strings.

Answer (score 3):

f is the name of the variable not the character 'f' !

you need to initialize `char f = 'f';`

Comment: Cheers, it worked!

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize the variable, because otherwise `c != f` is comparing `c` with whatever indeterminate value happens to be in the `f` variable.

If you want to test whether they typed the letter `f`, you should be comparing with a literal, not a variable.

```
do {
    c = getchar();
    count++;
} while (c != 'f');
```

Answer (score 0):

> How do I initialize a character?

You does not initialize a character, you initialize a variable.

> And why do I need to?

When you declare a local variable, this variable are allocated on the stack and it's value is the current value into that position at the stack (i.e. garbage).

So you need to set a value to that variable to avoid a undefined behavior of the program. In your specif case this value is: 'f'. The single quotes means that f is a character, this is the type of data that your variable (char) expects.