# How to specify End of file (EOF) in C online compiler like in jdoodle?

Tags: c

This is a program for copying content from one file to other file. How to specify EOF in online compiler so that my code will run as expected??

Link for online editor--->
https://www.jdoodle.com/c-online-compiler

//code for copying content--->>

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
char ch;
FILE *p,*q;
p=fopen("data.txt","w");
while(ch=getchar()!=EOF)
{
    putc(ch,p);
}

fclose(p);
p=fopen("data.txt","r");
q=fopen("newdata.txt","w");
while(ch=getc(p)!=EOF)
{
    putc(ch,q);
}

fclose(p);
fclose(q);
q=fopen("newdata.txt","r");
while(ch=getc(q)!=EOF)
{
    printf("\n%c",ch);
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with the expression `ch=getchar()!=EOF`:

1. The first is that [`getchar`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/getchar) returns an `int`. This is actually important for the `EOF` comparison.
2. The second problem is about [*operator precedence*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence). You expression is really `ch = (getchar() != EOF)`. That is, you assign the result of the *comparison* (which is an `1` or `0`) to the variable `ch`.

To solve the first problem, define the variable `ch` as an `int`.

To solve the second problem use explicit parentheses: `(ch = getchar()) != EOF`.

Comment: Your 2nd point is correct. But in the Ist point getchar() is a function which is used for reading inputs from keyboard. It reads single character at a time.

Comment: @rohitgoelrg [please read and understand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)