# Advice needed on loops and characters

Tags: c, for-loop, char

I'm writing a simple code that will read in a series of characters which terminates upon reading in '\n' character/ typing enter. The code will also only read in a maximum of 50 characters. However, I am receiving errors when compiling, segmentation fault. I am unsure why the loop is not ending despite taking in '\n' character.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <ctype.h>
 #define MAX 50

 int main(void){
     char str[MAX] = "0";             //initialise 1st char for the loop
     int i;
     printf("Enter your sentence, at most 50 character: \n");
     for(i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++){          //terminates upon \n
        str[i] = getchar();
        putchar(str[i]);
     }
     return 0;
 }
```

However, I tried moving the loop condition into the loop itself and use the if-break combo, it works perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define MAX 50

int main(void){
    char str[MAX] = "0";             //initialise 1st char for the loop
    int i;
    printf("Enter your sentence, at most 50 character: \n");
    for(i = 0;; i++){          //terminates upon \n
        str[i] = getchar();
        putchar(str[i]);
        if(str[i] == '\n')
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can any pros please explain to me why is this so and how do I correct it? Thanks a lot in advance! :)

RESOLVED. I'm checking the wrong element in the array. LOL.

Comment: The increment step in a `for(init;test;incr)` happens *before* the test once the loop is entered. Think about that for a minute. What are you *reallly* comparing to `'\n'` in your first code sample.

Comment: Check for MAX never is done. C doenst make such test for You -> so exception

Comment: OMG thanks! Totally didnt realise that despite staring at it for so long.

Comment: At first iteration , you try to check str[0] != '\n' but you have not yet taken str[0] character in input.

Comment: @sopho-saksham that's what the `"0"` initial value is for. Look again at the code.

Comment: Yeah. I got it now . It will be problematic after first iteration.
Thanks @WhozCraig for pointing out my mistake.

Comment: [`getchar` returns an `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn how `for` loop works.

The

```
for(expr1; expr2; expr3)  // lack of expr2 means 'forever'
    instr;
```

is equivalent to

```
expr1;
while(expr2)  // expr2 is replaced with 'true' if empty
{
    instr;
    expr3;
}
```

So in your case

```
for(i = 0; str[i] != '\n'; i++)
```

the test `str[i] != '\n'` is calculated *after* the increment `i++`, hence it tests the *wrong* element of the array – the one *past* the one just read!

Additionally, you do not check the length of input data, so if you enter an input line longer than 50 characters, your loop will try to store the tail of a line *past the end of declared array*, which triggers an Undefined Behavior.

**EDIT**

A simple way to fulfill both criteria is to do both tests:

```
char str[MAX];
int i;

// print the actual value of defined maximum
printf("Enter your sentence, at most %d character: \n", MAX);

for(i = 0; i < MAX; i++){  // test the length
    str[i] = getchar();
    if(str[i] == '\n')     // test the input char
        break;
    putchar(str[i]);
 }
```

Comment: @AmateurCoder Please see the expanded answer.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because in the first case after `str[i] = getchar();`  ,the  `i++` statement  executes before `str[i] != '\n';` condition cheking . So the checking fails in your first  code.

Try this modified `for-loop`:-

```
for(i = 0; (str[i] = getchar()) != '\n'; i++){     //Here checking happens while reading itself.
        putchar(str[i]);
     }
```

Remember that after the `body of` the `for-loop` executes, the flow of control jumps back up to the `increment statement` not to `condition-cheking`.