# C program to check for presence of ternary operator

Tags: c, operator-keyword, ternary

I am unable to find out if the ternary operator is present or not through following code.. Plz help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
void one();
int main()
{
    FILE *fp;
    fp=fopen("C:/Users/HP/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CD2/1.txt","r");
    char c;
    void one()
    {
        char c;
        while((c=fgetc(fp)!=EOF))
            {
                if(c==':')
                {
                    printf("\nThe ternary operator present");
                    return;
                }
            }
    }
    while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
    {
        printf("\n-->%c",c);
        if(c=='?')
        {
            one();
        }
     }

    return 0;
}
```

**I want to know why this code doesn't work and say if the ternary operator is present or not in file 1.txt**

*The output shows all characters till '?' if we print them, but why it's not finding for a colon ':' ?*

Comment: I suspect you're reading the file twice, with the second time which does nothing because the file has reached EOF.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre : let's suppose that they are not nested,then too the presence of ?: is not detected..

Comment: you're using the same file handle the second time. Why not checking for both ? and : in the first loop? (because the second time the file handle is at the end of the file and nothing is detected)

Comment: make a variable to look for "?" then ":" instead. That's not going to detect the ternary (lots of false alarms, though)

Comment: Note that getchar() returns an int, not char. That's one more bug in your program.

Comment: @RajChauhan My bad, I meant to say fgetc(). Same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exit condition of the `while` loop may be the problem. `=` has lesser precedence than `!=` operator. So

```
(c=fgetc(fp)!=EOF)
```

gets evaluated like

```
(c= (fgetc(fp)!=EOF) )
```

See [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) for the precedence of various operators in C.

You could do

```
while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF)
```

instead. First assign the return value of `fgetc()` to `c` and then do the comparison.

ie, the variable `c` gets the result of the comparison which means the value is either `0` or `1`.

Your program should be checking for the `?` and the other operands as well.
See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C).

A simple check may not be enough for cases like the 'operator' being part of a string like

```
char str[]="the ternary operator is ?:";
```

Checking for the occurrence in such cases is a bit complex.

Edit:
As [Jens](https://stackoverflow.com/users/648658/jens) pointed out, `fgetc()` returns an `int` not a `char`. So make `c` an `int` instead of a `char`.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc) post.

Comment: while((c=fgetc(fp))!=EOF) -- this worked! Thnx. a little yet powerful concept of operator precedence.

Comment: @RajChauhan No it doesn't work. It fails (terminates prematurely before the end-of-file) when there's a character with code 255 in the input which gets sign-extended to -1, the value of the EOF macro.

Comment: @RajChauhan You must use `int c;` instead of `char c;` since an int can fit all char values plus another for EOF.