# Reading from two different files and printing to third one

Tags: c, file

I need to read from 2 different files and print words to third one, first i read from file1 and save first word to file third, then read from file2 and save first word from here to third file as second word and so on.. and also words from file1 have "+" at the start of the word and from file2 have "-". My problem is that code doesnt stop and is still working and printig to third file "."(lot of dots). thanks

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    FILE *first, *second, *third;
    char ch[256],ch1[256],ch2;
    int i=1,count;
    char space = ' ';
    char minus = '-';
    char plus = '+';

    first=fopen("prvy.txt", "r");
    second=fopen("druhy.txt", "r");
    third=fopen("treti.txt", "w");

        if(first==NULL || second==NULL || third==NULL)
        {
        printf("error");
        exit(1);
        }

        while (fscanf(first, "%255s", ch) == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }

        while (fscanf(second, "%255s", ch) == 1)
        {
            count++;
        }

        printf("%d",count);

        for(i;i<=count;i++)
        {
            if(i%2==1)
            {
                fputc(plus,third);
                ch2=fgetc(first);
                while(ch2 != EOF || ch2 != ' ')
                    putc(ch2,third);
                    ch2=fgetc(first);
            }
            else if(i%2==0)
            {
                fputc(minus,third);
                ch2=fgetc(second);
                while(ch2 != EOF || ch2 != ' ')
                    putc(ch2,third);
                    ch2=fgetc(second);
            }
                fputc(space,third);         
        }


    fclose(first);
    fclose(second);
    fclose(third);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `count` is uninitialized

Comment: yes, but thats not the biggest problem. thanks

Comment: Instead of that useless `printf("error")` consider adopting `perror("error")` instead - it would provide a human-readable message telling what goes wrong!

Comment: using it without initializing it invokes undefined behavior. `count++` is going to add to whatever garbage value happened to be there, it's impossible to know how many times your `for` loop will execute.

Comment: [`fgetc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc) returns an int.

Comment: count sure is the issue. You loop until you reach count, if count is 4000000 you are going to keep going for a long time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the two `while` loops here:

```
        if(i%2==1)
        {
            fputc(plus,third);
            ch2=fgetc(first);
            while(ch2 != EOF || ch2 != ' ')
                putc(ch2,third);
                ch2=fgetc(first);
        }
        else if(i%2==0)
        {
            fputc(minus,third);
            ch2=fgetc(second);
            while(ch2 != EOF || ch2 != ' ')
                putc(ch2,third);
                ch2=fgetc(second);
        }
```

The first issue is that `ch2 != EOF || ch2 != ' '` will always be true.  If `ch2` is EOF, the first condition is false but the second is true.  If `ch2` is a space, the second condition will be false and the first will be true.  If it is neither, both are true.

You want to check if `ch` is **both** not EOF **and** not a space:

```
while(ch2 != EOF && ch2 != ' ')
```

This *would* work if not for this:

```
char ch[256],ch1[256],ch2;
```

You have `ch2` defined as a `char`, while `fgetc` returns an `int`.  The value `EOF` is out of range for a `char`, so you'll never see that value.  Change it to `int`:

```
char ch[256],ch1[256]
int ch2;
```

Your `while` loops also don't have any braces around them.  So what you actually have is:

```
            while(ch2 != EOF || ch2 != ' ') {
                putc(ch2,third);
            }
            ch2=fgetc(first);
```

`ch2` never changes inside of the loop, so you have an infinite loop.  Put braces where they belong:

```
        if(i%2==1)
        {
            fputc(plus,third);
            ch2=fgetc(first);
            while(ch2 != EOF && ch2 != ' ') {
                putc(ch2,third);
                ch2=fgetc(first);
            }
        }
        else if(i%2==0)
        {
            fputc(minus,third);
            ch2=fgetc(second);
            while(ch2 != EOF && ch2 != ' ') {
                putc(ch2,third);
                ch2=fgetc(second);
            }
        }
```

On top of this, the file pointers for both `first` and `second` are at the end of each file before you enter the `for` loop, so there's nothing to read.

You need to call `rewind(first)` and `rewind(second)` before entering this loop.

Finally, `count` is not initialized.  It could contain some randomly large number, so your loop could run many more times than you intend.

Be sure to set it to 0:

```
int i=1,count=0;
```

Comment: thanks, solves many problems but my program still doesnt print characters to third file  @dbush

Comment: @Rudolph Did you add the `rewind` calls **before** the `for` loop?

Comment: you are god @dbush