# C: Convert char to float

Tags: c

I want to convert a char to a float in language C.
But atof() and strtof() are not working.

Here is some code, maybe someone could help me!
The difficulty is that my number has a e-02 included

```
char temp = "6.345e-02"; // the original value is read from a file
float result;

result = atof(temp); //not working correct
result = strtof(temp, NULL); //also not working correct
```

edit: new code

```
FILE *file = fopen("file.txt", "r");
char c;
char *temp[11];
float result;
while((c=fgetc(file))!=EOF){
  if(c=='\t'){
    result = atof(temp); //here is the converting problem
    printf("%.6f\n", result);
  } else {
    temp[i] = c;
  }
}
```

Comment: `char *temp = "6.345e-02";`

Comment: Then show us the [mcve] with expected and actual results.

Comment: Read compiler warnings. Any C compiler must give you an error or warning message for this code. If yours doesn't, uninstall the crap.

Comment: Terminating your `temp` string you must... And initialize `i` to 0 first... Also: `fgetc` returns an `int`, not a `char`.

Comment: You don't print your result. How did you check if it works?

Comment: ...and also write `char temp[11];` you must.

Comment: The "new code" is nothing like the "original" one. Please, *always* provide [mcve] in the future (you still haven't provided one by the way..).

Comment: You changed your code again. Please avoid creating a moving target. No one wants to waste time for an answer that is useless after the next change. And please provided the output you get. Together with minimum **complete** example.

Comment: [`getchar` returns an **`int`**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35356322/918959)

Answer (score 1):

You're declaring `temp` as a single character which is not. 
It's a character array so it must be declared as `char *temp` instead.

Comment: Question has changed, the answer is no longer valid.

Comment: @Jabberwocky which is actually the problem of the question...

Answer (score 1):

I ran this on [IDEOne](https://ideone.com/t10Nrc), and found that if I don't `#include <stdlib.h>`, I got incorrect results

```
#include <stdio.h>
//#include <stdlib.h>            // <== This line is crucial

int main(void) {
    char* temp   = "6.345e-2";
    float result = atof(temp);

    printf("%f\n", result);

    return 0;
}
```

#### With `stdlib.h:`

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
0.063450
```

---

#### Without `stdlib.h`:

```
Success #stdin #stdout 0s 9424KB
0.000000
```

Comment: Question has changed, the answer is no longer valid.