# I cannot read in a number using getchar()

Tags: c, int, stdio, getchar

Programming noob here. I have an assignment where I have to read in a number using `getchar()` and perform some operations on it. The number can either be a positive or negative number. This is the segment of my code that takes in input. I can't find the issue but it returns something else.

I am using the general way of converting characters to integers by first multiplying an accumulator by `10`, then converting the character to its digit equivalent using `(ch -'0')` and adding it to the accumulator,

I have tried removing the validation for negative numbers but it still doesn't make a difference.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int accumulator = 0;
    char ch;
    int negative = 0;

    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == '-') {
        negative = -1;
        ch = getchar();
    }

    if (isdigit(ch) == 0) {
        puts("\nError: Not valid number.\nPlease try again");
        EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n') {
        ch = getchar();
        if ((ch = getchar()) == EOF) {
            break;
        }
        if (!isdigit(ch)) {
            puts("\nError: Not valid number.\nPlease try again");
            break;
            EXIT_FAILURE;
        }

        accumulator = accumulator * 10;
        accumulator = (ch = '0') + accumulator;
    }

    if (negative == -1)
        accumulator = accumulator * negative;

    printf("%d", accumulator);
}
```

Example

Input: `2351`
Output: `2351` (Using `getchar`)

Input: `-5689`
Output: `-5689` (Using `getchar`)

Comment: Your code appears to succeed in both of your examples. Can you give an example of it failing?

Comment: The `while` loop is calling `getchar()` multiple times. It calls it once in the `while()` condition, then it calls it again in the first line. So the character that it tested in `while()` is being ignored. Then it calls it again in `if ((ch == getchar()) == EOF)`, so the character it read on the previous line is ignored.

Comment: @Beta I think the examples at the bottom are what it's supposed to return, not what it actually returns.

Comment: [`ch` must be an `int`, not `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Comment: @AlistairAlva: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score

Answer (score 1):

You're calling `getchar()` too many times in your `while` loop. Each of them is discarding the result of the previous call. You should just use the result of the `getchar()` call in the `while()` condition, not call it again.

You're also not saving the character you read before the loop into the accumulator.

You have a typo in `ch = '0'`, that should be `ch - '0'`.

You need to declare `ch` to be `int`, not `char`, because `EOF` is not a character.

`EXIT_FAILURE` should be `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`. And you shouldn't put `break;` before it, since that will terminate the loop, skipping over the `exit()` call.

You can initialize `negative` to `1`, so at the end you can just multiply by it without having to test the value first. In this case, a better name for the variable is `sign`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int accumulator = 0;
    int ch;
    int sign = 1;

    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == '-') {
        sign = -1;
        ch = getchar();
    }

    if (!isdigit(ch)) {
        puts("\nError: Not valid number.\nPlease try again");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    accumulator = ch - '0';

    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF) {
        if (!isdigit(ch)) {
            puts("\nError: Not valid number.\nPlease try again");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        accumulator *= 10;
        accumulator += (ch - '0');
    }

    accumulator *= sign;

    printf("%d", accumulator);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- `ch` must be defined with type `int` to accommodate for all values returned by `getchar()`.
- you should test for `EOF` at the top of the `while` loop.
- `EXIT_FAILURE` is an argument value for the `exit()` function. Use it as `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.
- you re-read a new character inside the `while` loop body instead of handling `ch`.

Here is a corrected version:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int accumulator = 0;
    int ch;
    int negative = 0;

    ch = getchar();
    if (ch == '-') {
        negative = -1;
        ch = getchar();
    } else (if (ch == '+') {
        ch = getchar();
    }   

    if (isdigit(ch) == 0) {
        puts("\nError: Not valid number.\nPlease try again");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        if (!isdigit(ch)) {
            puts("\nError: Not valid number.\nPlease try again");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        accumulator = accumulator * 10 + (ch = '0');
    }
    if (negative < 0)
        accumulator = -accumulator;

    printf("%d\n", accumulator);
    return 0;
}
```