# How to test if a file is open/closed in different functions in C

Tags: c

I need to write *separate functions* for opening/closing the file and working with it. Was recommended to not use global variables in it.

I have a function where I need to open the file and print what's in it(`open_file`), a second to work with the data in it(`do_stuff_in_file`), and a third to only close the file and exit the program(`close_file`).

When I try to call `do_stuff_in_file` or `close_file` the program just crashes.

I know I'm supposed to use pointers, but I just can't get it right and I don't know where's the mistake.

```
int open_file(FILE **fr) {
    if ((fr = fopen("soldcars.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
    printf("File was not opened\n");
    return 1;
    }
    else {
        char testchar;

        while ((testchar = fgetc(fr)) != EOF) {
            ungetc(testchar, fr);
            //just printing whats in the file
        }
    }   
    return 0;
}
int do_stuff_in_file(FILE **fr, int date) {
    if (fr==NULL) {
        printf("File not open yet\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else{ fseek(fr, 0, SEEK_SET); } //doing stuff
    return 0;
}
int close_file(FILE **fr) {
    if (fr==NULL) { 
        printf("It was not even open yet\n");
        return 1; 
    }
    else{
        if (fclose(fr) == EOF) {
            printf("File was not successfully closed");
            return 1;
        }
        else{
            printf("Adios");
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
int main() {
    char input;
    int date;
    FILE* fr;
    fr = NULL;

    while ((input = getchar()) != 'c') {
        if (input == 'o') open_file(&fr);
        else if (input == 'd') {
            scanf("%d", &date);
            do_stuff_in_file(&fr, date);
        }
    }

    if (input == 'c') {
        close_file(&fr);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check your compiler warnings.

Comment: `char testchar;` -> `int testchar;` - As `fgetc` returns an `int` for a reason (EOF)

Comment: why are you passing to the functions ```File **``` instead of just ```File *```?

Comment: @EdHeal Oh yeah, I forgot that. Thanks

Comment: @JohnSmith Since I get files into the program with a pointer, so when I want to reference that pointer I need another pointer for it - at least that's what I was thinking

Comment: [Here what happens with `char testchar`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to dereference properly.  eg

```
int open_file(FILE **fr) {
    if ((*fr = fopen("soldcars.txt", "r")) == NULL) {
        perror( "soldcars.txt" );
        return 1;
    }
```

Note `*fr = open` instead of `fr = open`.  And, in that function, always use `*fr`, as in `fgetc(*fr)` vice `fgetc(fr)`.  Similarly in the other functions.  Because `fr` is not a `FILE *`, but `*fr` is.