# How does c structure loop? why is the variable not assigned the value at position (2) of the program? it only prints in position (1)?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char c;
    char d[10000];
    int i = 0, nl = 0,ll = 0,k = 0;
    int maxi = 0;
    while((c=getchar()) != EOF){
        d[i]=c;
        if(c == '\n'){
            ++nl;
            ll = i - k; //line length
            k = i;
            if(maxi<=ll){
                maxi=ll;
                printf("%d",maxi); //**(1)**
            }
        }
        ++i;
    }
    // printf("%d",maxi); **(2)**
}
```

why is the variable not assigned the value at position (2) of the program? it only prints in position (1)?

Comment: regarding: `while((c=getchar()) != EOF)`  the function: `getchar()` returns a `int` not a `char`.  In most circumstances, a `char` will fail to compare to `EOF`.  Suggest:  `int c; ... while( (c = getchar() ) != EOF)`

Comment: exactly what was the input you passed to the program?

Comment: what is `position 2`?  what is `structure`?

Comment: [Difference between int and char in getchar/fgetc and putchar/fputc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Comment: i want to print out the total number of letters in longest word, and when printf is as marker 1 it gives the output but when it is at marker 2 it doesnt even return a value.

Answer (score 1):

You should get into the habit of putting a newline (`\n`) at the end of your printf formats. That will usually make the data easier to read, and it will mostly save you from having to think about `stdout` buffering. (q.v.)

Also, I've heard that some IDEs swallow the last line of output if it's not terminated with a newline.

Sometimes, of course, you will want to use more than one `printf` call to print a single line; in that case, you only put the `\n` for the last printf in the line. But the normal case is that every format string ends with `\n`.