# How do properly divide in a for loop? And how do I control the size of the result?

Tags: c

```
    printf("Enter the number of gallons used for tank#1: ");
    scanf("%.f", &number);
    while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);
    printf("Enter the number of miles driven:");
    scanf("%.f", &y);
    while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF);
    div = number / y;
    printf("***The miles per gallon for this tank is %d\n\n", number, y, div);
```

I am using a for loop here, the only problem I have with this section is the division of `number` and `y`.

Every time I try to do so the result isn't calculated, it'll give me a random number or an extremely long number.

Comment: [I hope `c` is an `int`...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)

Comment: And also your compiler should be yelling at you with warnings about your print formats not matching. Always compiler with warnings enabled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems in your code:

- you did not post the definition of `number`, `y` or `div`. Given the computation you want to perform and the `scanf()` conversion, they should be defined as `float` or `double`.
- the `scanf()` conversion format is invalid: there should ve not `.` in `%.f`. Either use `%f` if the variables have type `float` or `%lf` if they have type `double`.
- You pass 3 variables to the last `printf` but only one format is present `%d`, which is incorrect for a floating point number, leading to undefined behavior, for example a meaningless sequence of digits.
- The division computes gallons per mile, not miles per gallon. Naming your variables with meaningful names is advisable.

Here is a modified version:

```
int compute_mileage(void) {
    double gallons, miles, mph;

    printf("Enter the number of gallons used for tank#1: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &gallons) != 1)
        return 1;
    while ((c = getchar() != EOF) && c != '\n')
        continue;
    printf("Enter the number of miles driven: ");
    if (scanf("%lf", &miles) != 1)
        return 1;
    while ((c = getchar() != EOF) && c != '\n')
        continue;
    mph = miles / gallons;
    printf("***The miles per gallon for this tank is %f\n\n", mph);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `printf()` function is wrong, because the format code if `%d` instead of `%f`. Most probably all your variables are `double`, but you don't show us this important information.

```
printf("***The miles per gallon for this tank is %f\n\n", div);
```

Please try it.

Comment: Given the `scanf()` conversion format, `number` should be a `float`.