# Copying the input from `getchar()` to another variable

Tags: c, char, getchar

In the following code example from K&R's book, if I replace `putchar(c)` with `printf("%c", c)` the code works the same. But if I replace it with `printf("%d", c)` it gives gibberish output.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
  int c;
  c = getchar();
  while (c != EOF) {
    putchar(c);
    c = getchar();
  }
}
```

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc/35356684), I learned that the `getchar()` converts the stdin to an 8-bit character whose value ranges from 0 to 255.

Now I want to print the value of `c` using `putchar(c)` in one line and `printf("%d", c)` in another line. So I wrote the following code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int c, b;

  c = getchar();
  b = c;
  while (c != EOF && c != 10) {
    printf("%c",c);
    c = getchar();
  }
  printf("\n");
  while (b != EOF && b != 10) {
    printf("%d\t",b);
    b = getchar();
  }
}
```

I used the condition `c != 10` as the newline character is read as `10` by `getchar()`. I expected the code to work as

```sh
$ ./a.out
783
783
55 56 51
```

but the program terminates as

```sh
$ ./a.out
783
783
55
```

I understand that `getchar()` takes input from stdin and the variable `b` is not stdin. So how should I copy the variable `c` to `b` so that my program works as I expect it to?

Comment: Nit, but using the character literal `'\n'` is much easier to understand when reading (for someone not familiar with the ASCII chart) than `10`. Use `'A'` when you mean `'A'` not `65` or `'a'` when you mean `'a'`, not `97`. Or `'\r'` when you mean `'\r'` instead of `13`, etc... -- makes things much more readable.

Comment: As `c` is an `int` variable, I thought of comparing it with an integer. But yes, `'\n'` works as well.

Comment: All character functions such as `getchar()` return `int` (which is actually the `unsigned char` value of the character cast to `int`), so you are good just comparing to the character literal in all cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your code does not (and cannot, as it stands) 'remember' the inputs you gave in the first loop. So, after you have finished that loop, your second loop is wanting to read in the characters for `b` (after it has output the first value, which is remembered from the earlier `b = c` line).

So, after outputting `55` (the integer *value* of the character `7`), it is waiting for further input.

Probably the easiest way to get the output that you're looking for is to have an **array** of input characters. Then, you can output the `%c` values as you read them (as before), then re-run the outputs using the `%d` format in a subsequent `for` loop.

Here is a demonstration that does what I think you're after:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXINS 20 // Set to the maximum number of input characters you want to allow
int main()
{
    int c[MAXINS];
    int i = 0, n = 0;
    c[0] = getchar();
    while (i < MAXINS && c[i] != EOF && c[i] != 10) {
        printf("%c", c[i]);
        c[++i] = getchar();
        ++n;
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        printf("%d\t", (int)(c[i]));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Feel free to ask for further clarification and/or explanation.

**EDIT**: On the point in the your first paragraph, *"But if I replace it with printf("%d", c) it gives gibberish output."* Well, when I try the following code and give `783` and then hit return (which generates a newline) I get the expected `55565110` as the output:

```c
int main()
{
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    while (c != EOF) {
        printf("%d", c);
        c = getchar();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This may look like gibberish, but it's just the same output as you 'expect' in your later code, but without the spaces and with the addition of the `10` for the newline.

Comment: Ah! I get it. `getchar()` copies only one character from stdin, that's why `c=getchar(); b=c;` copies only one character to `b`. Though you have answered my question completely, I was wondering if there is a way to solve it without using an array.

Comment: Without using complex cursor-positioning stuff, you would *have* to use an array of some sort. You could use two *output* arrays (rather than an input array), writing the outputs (in one loop) to two different strings, then printing them after your loop exits.

Comment: @DeusExMachina If you don´t necessarily need to output the character and integer values subsequently with each other and also do not need to have `b`, you can simply use one loop and output it via `printf("%c %d\n",c,c);`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have every character stored, because once you read a `char` from `stdin`, it is not present in `stdin` anymore.

Since you want the newline character in the end as a part of the input, you should use `fgets` to take the input.

Say you are taking an input that could have a maximum of 100 characters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char c[100]; // A char array
    fgets(c,100,stdin);
    int x=0;
    while (c[x] != 10 && c[x] != EOF)
        printf("%c",c[x++]);
    printf("\n");
    x = 0;
    while (c[x] != 10 && c[x] != EOF) // You can simply compare it with the newline character too.
        printf("%d ",c[x++]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

There are many ways to do this. You can also read `stdin` character-by-character ans store it in an array. However, since you need to display the ASCII values of the characters in another line after displaying the characters themselves, you will have to store them in an array.

Comment: Yeah, `fgets`is the solution, but it seems that OP is doing some learning-test with `getchar`

Comment: Correct! And they would still need to store all the characters in an array to be able to display each character's ASCII value after displaying the characters themselves.

Answer (score 1):

You are copying only the first input, to copy the whole string you need to store each input in a buffer and check if the string doesn't overflow that buffer on each iteration:

```
int main(void)
{
    enum {size = 256};
    char buffer[size];
    size_t count = 0;
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) && (c != '\n') && (c != EOF))
    {
        printf("%c", c);
        if (count < size)
        {
            buffer[count++] = (char)c;
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
    for (size_t iter = 0; iter < count; iter++)
    {
        printf("%d\t", buffer[iter]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

If you don't want to limit the buffer to an arbitrary size then you need to change your approach to use dynamic memory (`realloc` or a linked list)

Comment: I get the answer. Here I have another question: if I replace `'\n'` of your code by `"\n"`, the compiler gives a warning `warning: comparison between pointer and integer`. Could you please explain why is that?

Comment: @DeusExMachina `'\n'` is as an `int` (with value 10) and can be compared with `c` (also an `int`), `"\n"` is a pointer to  `char`, hence the warning, comparing a pointer (an address like 0xdeadbeef) with an `int` doesn't make sense.