# Why should I press ENTER before CTRL+D to indicate an EOF to stdin?

Tags: c, shell, unix, input, stdin

The following is my code, where I use `fgetc` to get input from `stdin`. (running the program from a UNIX shell)

What I don't understand is that, when I type some characters from the keyboard, and then I press `ctrl + D` and then press `ENTER`, the program does not stop. It seems to me that `EOF` has already been transmitted to the program, why wouldn't it stop?

I also found that if I press `ENTER`, then `ctrl + D`, the program does stop, but why?

```c
#include "stdio.h"

int main()
{
    char ch;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 200; i++)
    {
        ch = fgetc(stdin);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you haven't typed any characters on a line, then one ^D will send EOF. If you've typed some characters, then press ^D twice to send EOF.

Comment: [**`int ch;`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356684/918959)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Saying that Ctrl-D sends EOF is an educational lie-to-children. What it actually does is make any ongoing `read()` from the terminal return immediately with the contents of the current line buffer if any.

Synergy happens because the Unix convention is that a `read()` of zero bytes represents EOF.

This means that if you press Ctrl-D with an empty buffer, the `read()` will return with zero bytes, and a canonical program will interpret it as end-of-file. This is obviously just an illusion since you're still there to input more on the terminal, and a less canonical program could just keep reading if it wanted to.

If you instead press Ctrl-D after entering some data, then that data is just returned and a canonical program will keep reading to find a linefeed or whatever else it's looking for.

This is why EOF behavior is only triggered in canonical programs when Ctrl-D is pressed either after another Ctrl-D (the first flushes the buffer, the second returns a now-empty buffer) or after an Enter (for the same reason).