# Back then, were char variables in C declared as unsigned by default?

Tags: c, char

Here is a code fragment from "The C Programming Language" by Kernighan and Ritchie.

```
#include <stdio.h>
/* copy input to output; 2nd version */
main()
{
   int c;
   while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
       putchar(c);
}
```

Justification for using `int c` instead of `char c`:

> ...We can't use **char** since **c** must be big enough to hold **EOF** in addition to any possible **char**.

I think using **int** instead of **char** is only justifiable if **c** is modified with **unsigned** because an signed **char** won't be able to hold
the value of **EOF** which is -1, and when I wrote this program `char c` was interpreted as `signed char c`, therefore I had no problem.

Were **char** variables previously **unsigned** by default? And if so, then why did they alter it?

Comment: *I think using int instead of char is only justifiable if c is modified with unsigned because an signed char won't be able to hold the value of EOF which is -1.*  It has nothing to do with signed or unsigned character.  If `getchar()` returned a `char` instead of an `int`, there would be no difference between the `char` with a value of `-1` or `EOF`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think using **int** instead of **char** is only justifiable if **c** is modified
> with **unsigned** because a signed **char** won't be able to hold the value of
> **EOF** which is -1.

Who says that `EOF` is -1? It is specified to be negative, but it doesn't have to be -1.

In any case, you're missing the point.  Signedness notwithstanding, `getchar()` needs to return a type that can represent more values than `char` can, because it needs to provide, in one way or another, for every `char` value, *plus* at least one value that is distinguishable from all the others, for use as `EOF`.

> Were char variables previously unsigned by default? And if so, then
> why did they alter it?

No.  But in C89 and pre-standard C, functions could be called without having first been declared, and the expected return type in such cases was `int`.  This is among the reasons that so many of the standard library functions return `int`.

Comment: Can you please specify what is the range of EOF, then?

Comment: @AritraChakrabary, the standard specifies only that `EOF` expands to an integer constant expression with type `int` and a negative value.  Assuming anything more specific about it reduces the portability of your program.

Answer (score 1):

The C Standard does not define whether or not `char` is signed or unsigned, that's why we also have `signed char` and `unsigned char`. This has been the case in K&R C and is still the case in C18. But this is not really relevant when looking at your actual question, we simply need to use `int` here because we need a type that can hold *more* values than `char` so that we can use one of them to signal `EOF`.

Comment: But we can simply use char as signed char can hold EOF

Comment: @AritraChakrabary: The Standard does not specify (to my knowledge) that `EOF` _has_ to be `-1`. Of course it does make sense for it to be this way and reserve the return values `0-255` for valid characters. But this is entirely independent from whether or not `char` is signed or unsigned. If it was signed, it still couldn't represent more than 256 values.

Comment: @peter a char can hold more than 256 values. it is just that it cannot hold *all possible* char values *and* distinct EOF

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: How would you propose to represent more then 256 distinct values using one byte? (I'm aware that a the C standard permits non-8-bit bytes but that is not exactly common).

Comment: @Peter just like so :D

Comment: @Peter I was thinking EOF is -1 but i was wrong; from that perspective though what i said was correct. A signed char will be able to hold EOF as its range will be -127 to 127

Answer (score 0):

Values and representations aside, the main reason we don’t use `char` to represent `EOF` is that it *isn’t a character* - it is a *condition* signaled by the input function when it reaches the end of the stream.  It is *logically* a different entity from a character value.

Answer (score 0):

[Why `int` is discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc).

But what comes to `char` being **unsigned** I believe is more common among architectures, and there are more devices in existence that have those architecture. But as one architecture (x86-16/32) has been popular among *newbie* programmers, that is often neglected. x86 is peculiar in that it has the move with sign extension *and* signed memory operands, which is why the signed `char` makes more sense there, whereas on majority of other architectures unsigned `char` is the more efficient one.