# Broken files in C

Tags: c, windows, file, stdio

I made a simple script to rewrite one file contents into another.
Here's code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char filename[1024];
    scanf("%s", &filename);

    // printf("Filename: '%s'\n", filename);

    int bytesToModify; scanf("%d", &bytesToModify);

    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int fSize = ftell(fp);
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);

    printf("%d\n", fSize);

    char *buf = malloc(fSize*sizeof(char));

    for (int i = 0; i < fSize; i++) {
        buf[i] = getc(fp);
    }
    fclose(fp);

    FILE *fo;

    fo = fopen("out_file.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < fSize; i++) {
        fwrite(&buf[i], 1, 1, fo);
    }
    fclose(fo);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Even on small file like this I can see the artifact. Cyrillic sybmol 'я' is coming in the end of file.
If I'll try to rewrite executable file, i get this:
[image]

99% of file just turned to these symbols. What is wrong with my code?

I'm using CodeBlocks with GCC Compiler, version 10.1.0.
My Operation System is Windows 10.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `fp = fopen(filename, "r");` ==> `fp = fopen(filename, "rb");` and similarly for `"out_file.txt"`

Comment: the returned value of `ftell` must be `long`, not `int`.  the same for the iterator `i`.

Comment: Whenever doing any sort of IO you need to be careful that you watch the encoding which is set via the [locale](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/locale/setlocale). Valid [locales on windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/locale-names-languages-and-country-region-strings?view=vs-2019) are a bit funky but still work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You did not open the file in **binary mode**: `"rb"` and `"wb"`. Therefore, `fgetc` will turn all `\r\n` to a single `\n`.
2. For each line terminator there is one character less read. Yet you attempt to read nevertheless, and `fgetc` will return **`EOF`** (and [`fgetc` returns an `int`, not `char`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356684/918959)). As `EOF` has value `-1` on Windows, when written to file converted to `unsigned char` this results in `Я` in the encoding you're using in Notepad (most likely [Windows-1251](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251)).

Furthermore, since you're using `fwrite`, then you could similarly use `fread`. And no need to read, write the characters *one at a time*, just use

```
char *buf = malloc(fSize);
int bytesRead = fread(buf, 1, fSize, fp); 
fclose(fp);
```

and

```
int bytesWritten = fwrite(buf, 1, bytesRead, fo);
```