# Why when I am using file.peek() in C++ do I get a number rather than the char?

Tags: c++

In most of my code, the `in.peek()` works as getting whatever the next char is supposed to be. However, when it is reading some symbols, it returns a number rather than the char, and I am not sure how to fix it to get the symbol I want.

The text file reads:

> print "Good morning!!";

but during the " char I use `file.peek()` to read the next symbol is a `;` to change the state of my switch, but it comes out as a number instead of the symbol.

This is how I am trying to print, I even created a temp `char` and set it to `in.peek()`, but that just comes out as a blank space.

```cpp
char temp = in.peek();
cout<<"hit  " << ch << " "<< in.peek()<<" "<<temp << endl;
```

The output is: `"hit  " 10 "`

With the last bit being a blank space. Does anyone know how I can fix this so I get the `;`?

Comment: according to the docs I see, it returns an int. That int may typically be displayed as a char in some places, presumably ascii?

Comment: Same reason why getchar and friends return int [Difference between int and char in getchar/fgetc and putchar/fputc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35356322/10147399)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`peek` returns an `int` (to account for possibility of `eof()`). To make sure `cout` recognizes it as a `char`, you can cast it (though this will produce incorrect values if you did hit EOF), e.g.:

```
cout << "hit  " << ch << " " << static_cast<char>(in.peek()) << " " << temp << endl;
```

Comment: Worked! Thanks so much, didn't know that.