# C program is skipping code statements while compiling and executing

Tags: c

The following code is for searching a string or character in another string :-

`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int strindex( char primary[] , char searchfor[]){

    int k;

    for(int i = 0 ; primary[i] != '\0' ; i++){
        for(int j = i , k = 0 ; (searchfor[k] != '\0') && (primary[j] == searchfor[k]) ; j++ , k++){
            ;
        }

    if( k > 0 && searchfor[k] == '\0'){
        return i;
        }

    }

    return -1; 
}

int line( char *str ){
    int i = 0;
    char c;

    for (;(c = getchar()) != '\n' && (c != EOF) ; i++){
        str[i] = c;
    }

    if( c = '\n') str[i] = '\n';
    str[++i] = '\0';

    return i;
}

int main(){

    char str1[100] , str2[100];

    int i ;

    puts("Enter the main string:-");
    line(str1);
    puts("Enter string to search for:-");
    line(str2);

    i = strindex(str1 , str2);

    if( i >= 0){
        printf("String found at index : %d \n",i);
    }else{
        puts("stirng not found.");
    }

    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

`

The compile result :-

```
PS E:\Workspace\C> gcc p1.c
PS E:\Workspace\C> ./a.exe
Enter the main string:-
this is a demo text
Enter string to search for:-
demo
PS E:\Workspace\C>
```

I am using visual studio code ,
As we can see that the "if-else" and "print"  statements after the function call are not being executed . I have tried a lot , but could not make it . Please someone help me and tell me where I am going wrong ??

Comment: `if( c = '\n') str[i] = '\n';` should be `if( c == '\n') str[i] = '\n';`

Comment: Instead of writing line function, why dont you use gets() function to read the input string?

Comment: is windows this bad, not showing crashes?

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: it's undefined behaviour. Even under Linux, I got different results with seemingly minor code changes away from the offending code. I don't think this is a Windows issue.

Comment: @AshishKhurange: you appear to have misspelt `fgets` :-) It's no accident that `gets` is one of the few things ever deprecated from ISO C, there's no safe way to use it.

Comment: @paxdiablo not asking that, I presume if it doesn't print anything then it indeed crashed, and in that case I as a user would be interested to hear it from the *operating system* ... :D

Comment: Also [`int c;`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35356684/918959)

Comment: @AnttiHaapala: re " I presume", that's the problem. UB means exactly that, undefined. It may crash, it may format all your local storage devices. It *might* even exit with a success code without printing :-)

Answer (score 3):

```c
int k;
for (int j = i, k = 0; ...) { blahBlahBlah(); }
doSomethingWith(k);
```

That `k` in the `for` loop is *not* the `k` declared before it, it's a *new* variable that shadows (hides) the original. That's because using `int` inside the `for` loop is a new declaration for all variables following it.

Then, when it comes time to `doSomethingWith(k)`, that's using the *original* `k`, as the other one has gone out of scope.

And, since that original `k` will have some arbitrary value, hilarity will ensue :-)

The quickest solution is probably to remove the declaration from the `for` statement:

```c
int j, k;
for (j = i, k = 0; ...) { blahBlahBlah(); }
doSomethingWith(k);
```

In your case, that would be along the lines of:

```c
int strindex(char *primary, char *searchfor) {
    int j, k;

    for (int i = 0; primary[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = i, k = 0; (searchfor[k] != '\0') && (primary[j] == searchfor[k]); j++, k++);
        if (k > 0 && searchfor[k] == '\0') return i;
    }
    return -1; 
}
```

---

As an aside, this is also a problem (in `line()`):

```c
if (c = '\n') str[i] = '\n'; // First = should be ==, anyway.
str[++i] = '\0';
```

It preserves the newline character so that you would be looking for `"demo\n"` in `"this is a demo text\n"`, which won't be found. Better to just use:

```c
str[i] = '\0';
```

---

And, on top of that, `c` should be an `int`, not a `char`. That's because it has to cater for all possible `char` values *and* `EOF`.

Comment: simple, but good point.

Comment: Other point is no need to store `\n` in searched string(`str2`) because you cannot have `\n` in middle of `str1` , so comparison may fail

Comment: @IrAM: good point, incorporated that as an aside.

Comment: just for completeness, `if( c = '\n')` should be `if( c == '\n')` :)