# I want to perform external sorting between two files and the data should print in an order according to a particular attribute in a third file

Tags: c, file-handling, external-sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student {
    int roll, age;
    char name[30], branch[30];
} s;

int main() {
    FILE *fp1, *fp2, *fp3;
    int num1, num2, i;
    char ch;
    printf("Enter the Number of Students to compute the data in 1st file: ");
    scanf("%d", &num1);
    fp1 = fopen("Dbms lab-1 1sttxt.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < num1; i++) {
        printf("\nEnter the Name of the Student: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", s.name);
        printf("Enter the Branch the Student is studying in: ");
        scanf("%[^\n]s", s.branch);
        printf("Enter the Age of the Student: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.age);
        printf("Enter the Roll Number: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.roll);
        fprintf(fp1, "\nName: %s\nBranch: %s\nAge: %d\nRoll.No: %d",
                s.name, s.branch, s.age, s.roll);
    }
    printf("The Record is stored in the file.");
    fclose(fp1);
    printf("\nEnter the Number of Students to compute data in 2nd file: ");
    scanf("%d", &num2);
    printf("\n\n Enter Student details in the second file");
    fp2 = fopen("Dbms lab-1 2ndtxt.txt", "w");
    for (i = 0; i < num2; i++) {
        printf("\n\nEnter the Name of the Student: ");
        scanf("%s", s.name);
        printf("\nEnter the Branch the Student is studying in: ");
        scanf("%s", s.branch);
        printf("\nEnter the Age of the Student: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.age);
        printf("\nEnter the Roll Number: ");
        scanf("%d", &s.roll);
        fprintf(fp1, "\nName: %s\nBranch: %s\nAge: %d\nRoll.No: %d",
                s.name, s.branch, s.age, s.roll);
    }
    printf("\nThe Record is stored in the file.");
    fclose(fp2);
    fp1 = fopen("Dbms lab-1 1sttxt.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("Dbms lab-1 2ndtxt.txt", "r");
    fp3 = fopen("Dbms lab-1 3rdtxt.txt", "w");
    if (fp1 == NULL || fp2 == NULL || fp3 == NULL) {
        printf("Could not open the file,because the file is empty");
        exit(0);
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp1) != EOF)) {
        putc(ch, fp3);
    }
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp2) != EOF)) {
        putc(ch, fp3);
    }
    printf("\nThe two files are successfully merged.");
    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    fclose(fp3);
    return 0;
}
```

I've merged data from 2 files into a single file. Now I want to perform external sorting in the third file. I want to sort the data based on the value of `roll`. How do I do it ? Can you help me with the code? Thank you.

Comment: **[`int ch;`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35356322/difference-between-int-and-char-in-getchar-fgetc-and-putchar-fputc)**

Comment: @VaibavReddy: you can accept one of the answers by clicking on the grey checkmark below its score.

Answer (score 1):

There are many problems in your code:

- `ch` must be defined with type `int` to store all possible values returned by `fgetc()` and properly distinguish `EOF` from all valid byte values,
- you should test the return value of `scanf()` to detect input errors. Each of your calls to `scanf()` must return `1` for success because there is a single conversion attempted in each call.
- `scanf("%[^\n]s", s.name);` is invalid for 2 reasons: the `s` after the `]` is useless, and you should pass the maximum number of characters to store to `s.name` to avoid buffer overflows on invalid input. Use this instead:

  ```
    if (scanf("%29[^\n]", s.name) != 1) {
        /* handle the input error */
    }
  ```
- the second `scanf("%[^\n]s", s.branch);` will fail because the newline was left pending in the input stream by the previous call to `scanf()`. You should flush the rest of the input line with this:

  ```
     int ch;
     while ((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n')
         continue;
  ```
- you use a different conversion for the second entry: `%s`, thus not allowing embedded spaces in the name or branch.
- you output both entries to `fp1`: the second `fprintf()` has undefined behavior because `fp1` has been closed.
- `fprintf(fp1, "\nName: %s\nBranch: %s\nAge: %d\nRoll.No: %d", ...)` outputs the data on 5 separate lines starting with a blank line, and ending the file without a trailing newline. This is inadequate. You should instead output the data on a single line with a trailing newline:

  ```
        fprintf(fp1, "Name: '%s'  Branch: '%s'  Age: %d  Roll.No: %d\n",
                s.name, s.branch, s.age, s.roll);
  ```

External sorting can be performed using the command line utility `sort`, but the option to sort based on the last numeric field are non trivial.  Writing code to perform this sorting in C seems challenging.  If you can assume that both files are entered in the expected order, you could merge them as you read them, one line at a time, comparing the last field as a number and writing the smaller one until one of the files is empty:

```
// merge the files: read one line from each file
//       compare the roll numbers and output the
//       line with the lesser number.
void merge_files(FILE *fp1, FILE *fp2, FILE *fp3) {
    char buf1[200], buf2[200];
    char *p1, *p2;
    int has1 = 0, has2 = 0;
    long roll1 = 0, roll2 = 0;
    for (;;) {
        if (!has1 && fgets(buf1, sizeof buf1, fp1)) {
            p1 = strstr(buf1, "Roll.No: ");
            roll1 = p1 ? strtol(p1 + 9, NULL, 10) : 0;
            has1 = 1;
        }
        if (!has2 && fgets(buf2, sizeof buf2, fp2)) {
            p2 = strstr(buf2, "Roll.No: ");
            roll2 = p2 ? strtol(p2 + 9, NULL, 10) : 0;
            has2 = 1;
        }
        if (has1 + has2 == 0)
            break;
        if (has2 == 0 || roll1 <= roll2) {
            fputs(buf1, fp3);
            has1 = 0;
        } else {
            fputs(buf2, fp3);
            has2 = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are attempting is far more complex than your method could achieve. There are too many shortcomings to properly clarify in a brief space. Primarily, the 3rd file should be the combination of records of the first two, but sorted by 'roll'. To attempt to 'merge' them (when records are split across 4 lines in each file) presumes that each 'batch' is sorted to begin with. To make matters worse, the 'sort key' has been 'tainted' with additional text (and is a string of digits, not a number.)

I've written (and trivially tested) a working version. Rather than 'copy/paste' of code, this version 're-uses' "input and storing" functions for the two batches of records.

Notice that the (reliable) library function `qsort()` is used to sort all the records in memory after the two lists have been joined into one, as you wanted. It's not hard to imagine writing and using a different `cmp()` function that would sort the records by `age` or by `name`, or even `subsorting` by `roll` within different `branches`.

Go very slowly reading through this working example. I hope it helps you become a better 'C' programmer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student {
    char name[30];
    char branch[30];
    int age;
    int roll;
} s_t;

typedef struct {
    s_t *p;
    int count;
} list_t;

void append( list_t *pl, s_t *s ) {
    s_t *tmp = (s_t*)realloc( pl->p, (pl->count + 1) * sizeof s_t );
    if( tmp == NULL )
        exit( 1 );
    pl->p = tmp;

    memcpy( pl->p + pl->count, s, sizeof pl->p[0] );
    pl->count++;
}

void writeBatch( char *fname, list_t *pl ) {
    FILE *fp;

    if( ( fp = fopen( fname, "w" ) ) == NULL )
        exit( 1 );

    for( int i = 0; i < pl->count; i++ ) {
        s_t *p = pl->p + i;
        fprintf( fp, "Name: %sBranch: %sAge: %d\nRoll.No: %d\n", p->name, p->branch, p->age, p->roll );
    }

    fclose( fp );
}

int enterOne( s_t *one ) {
    printf("Student Name: ");
    fgets( one->name, sizeof one->name, stdin );

    if( strncmp( one->name, "end", 3 ) == 0 )
        return 0;
    
    printf("Branch where student studies: ");
    fgets( one->branch, sizeof one->branch, stdin );

    char tbuf[32];
    printf("Student's age: ");
    fgets( tbuf, sizeof tbuf, stdin );
    one->age = atoi( tbuf );

    printf("Student's Roll Number: ");
    fgets( tbuf, sizeof tbuf, stdin );
    one->roll = atoi( tbuf );

    return 1;
}

void enterBatch( list_t *pl, int batchNo, char *fname ) {
    printf( "(Enter \"end\" as student name to finish this batch)\n" );
    printf( "Begin batch No. %d:\n", batchNo );

    memset( pl, 0, sizeof *pl );

    s_t s;
    while( enterOne( &s ) )
        append( pl, &s );

    writeBatch( fname, pl );
    printf( "Records stored to %s.\n\n", fname );
}

int cmp( const void *px, const void *py ) {
    return ((s_t *)px)->roll - ((s_t *)py)->roll;
}

int my_main() {
    list_t list1; enterBatch( &list1, 1, "Dbms lab-1 1sttxt.txt" );
    list_t list2; enterBatch( &list2, 2, "Dbms lab-1 2ndtxt.txt" );

    if( list1.count == 0 && list2.count == 0 ) {
        printf( "That was a waste of time.\n" );
        return 0;
    }

    for( int i = 0; i < list2.count; i++ )
        append( &list1, list2.p + i );
    
    qsort( list1.p, list1.count, sizeof *list1.p, cmp );

    writeBatch( "Dbms lab-1 3rdtxt.txt", &list1 );

    if( list1.p ) free( list1.p );
    if( list2.p ) free( list2.p );

    printf("\nTwo files written. Sorted version in third file.");

    return 0;
}
```