# for loop to print array does not execute properly for output (C)

Tags: c, output

I am trying to print the final results of the calculations using my program and put it into a clean organized table for the output, however, when the table is printed it doesn't print properly and I am very lost and my professor isn't really much help. Any help is greatly appreciated thank you!

The table is meant to look like this:

[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S4y8y.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(void) {
  float sale[10], pct[10], commission[10];
  char emp_name[10][20], company[15];
  float sum = 0;

  char c;
  int i, x, sales_persons, num_of_sales;

  printf("Enter your company name: ");
  scanf("%s", company);

  printf("\nWelcome to the %s Sales Analysis\n", company);

  do {
    printf("\nEnter how many sales persons from 1 to 10: ");
    scanf("%i", &sales_persons);
    while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF)
      ; /* clear input buffer */

    if (sales_persons < 0 || sales_persons > 10)
      printf("Number of sales persons must be 1-10...\n\n");

  } while (sales_persons < 0 || sales_persons > 10);

  for (x = 0; x < sales_persons; x++) {
    printf("\nEnter the name of sales person #%i: ", x + 1);
    scanf("%19[^\n]", emp_name[x]);
    while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF)
      ;

    do {
      printf("Enter the number of sales for %s (1 - 20): ", emp_name[x]);
      scanf("%i", &num_of_sales);

      while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF)
        ; /* clear input buffer */

      if (num_of_sales < 0 || num_of_sales > 20)
        printf("Number of sales must be 1-20...\n\n");

    } while (num_of_sales < 0 || num_of_sales > 20);

    do {
      printf("Enter the commission percentage for %s (1-50): ", emp_name[x]);
      scanf("%f", &pct[x]);
      while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF)
        ; /* clear input buffer */

      if (pct[x] < 0 || pct[x] > 50) printf("Percent must be 0-50...\n\n");

    } while (pct[x] < 0 || pct[x] > 50);

    printf("\n");

    for (x = 0; x < num_of_sales; x++) {
      do {
        printf("  Sale #%i for %s: ", x + 1, emp_name[x]);
        scanf("%f", &sale[x]);
        while ((c = getchar() != '\n') && c != EOF)
          ; /* clear input buffer */

        if (sale[x] < 0) printf("All sales must be greater than 0...\n\n");

      } while (sale[x] < 0);
    }

    sum = sum + sale[x];
    commission[x] = pct[x] * sum / 100;
  }

  printf("\n\n\n    *** %s Sales Commission Report ***", company);
  printf("\n\n\nName \t\t Sales \t\t Commission");
  printf("\n---- \t\t ----- \t\t ----------");

  for (x = 0; x < sales_persons; x++) {
    printf("\n%s \t\t %.2f\n \t\t%.2f", emp_name[x], sum, commission[x]);
  }
  getchar();
}
```

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: **_Strongly_** recommend you use an array of structs to aggregate your data rather than parallel arrays. That way lies madness.

Comment: @Chris Unfortunately im not allowed to as we havent learned that yet and would get points off If I used that

Comment: You collect up to **20** "sales" amounts into an array dimensioned for **10** items... Time to carefully examine what it is you are accumulating to print in the final loop...

Comment: @Fe2O3 I know thats outta place, theres a lot out of place because my professor is not the brightest but if i tell him hes wrong he marks me down lol. He told us to make the error condition 10 but the print 20 lol

Answer (score 1):

You are using the same `x` variable to control nested loops

```
for (x = 0; x < sales_persons; x++) {
    /* ... */
    for (x = 0; x < num_of_sales; x++) {
```

meaning the line

```
printf("  Sale #%i for %s: ", x + 1, emp_name[x]);
```

will access incorrect elements of `emp_name`, and the value of `x` will be `num_of_sales + 1` after every outer loop.

Similarly,

```
sum = sum + sale[x];
commission[x] = pct[x] * sum / 100;
```

will be working with the wrong value of `x` after the inner loop completes.

Perhaps the unused variable `i` should be substituted for `x` in the inner loop?

Additionally, this format string has a stray newline in it, making the output of the program confusing:

```
printf("\n%s \t\t %.2f\n \t\t%.2f", emp_name[x], sum, commission[x]);
                   /* ^^^ excess newline character */
```

---

Other problems:

- `void main(void)` should be `int main(void)`.
- `char c;` should be `int c;`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35356322/2505965).
- `scanf("%s", company);` is inviting [undefined behaviour](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/behavior) by not limiting the size of the input string (`"%14s"`).
- Newline characters should ideally be written at the end of lines.
- A lot of repeated code should be placed in separate functions (clearing the input buffer, for example).

Comment: Okay so I changed every x in the inner loop to i and im still getting the same error as well as changing to int main (void) also changed sum = sum + sale[x]; commission[x] = pct[x] * sum / 100;     to all i's as well im kinda lost lol

Comment: That's a lot of debugging right there. If you're trying to just get the numbers to line up, [man printf](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xsh/fprintf.html) will probably help.

Comment: `sum = ...` and `commission[x] = ...` are in the block of the outer loop, and should not use the value of `i`.